# Why isn't my JavaScript working in JSFiddle?

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

I can't find out what is the problem with this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yazpj/).

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="test()">
```

JavaScript:

```
function test(){alert("test");}
```

And when I click on button - nothing happened. The console says "test not defined"

I've read the JSFiddle documentation - there it says that JS code is added to `<head>` and HTML code is added to `<body>` (so this JS code is earlier than html and should work).

Comment: Removing the parentheses would also work under normal non fiddle circumstances though it is definitely good advice to separate js from HTML as much as possible.  I only allow myself the style =" display:none" CSS inline no-no.

Comment: related: [JavaScript not running on jsfiddle.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468350/javascript-not-running-on-jsfiddle-net)

Comment: If you’re looking for the _opposite_ problem — i.e. the code works in JSFiddle, but not locally — see [Using document.getElementById() inside object, works in JSFiddle, TypeError in actual. Why?](/q/15572630/4642212). Both behaviors have the same cause: JSFiddle automatically wraps JS code in a function that is executed as soon as the DOM is ready, which also causes `onclick` to be out of scope.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The function is being defined inside a load handler and thus is in a different scope.  As @ellisbben notes in the comments, you can fix this by explicitly defining it on the `window` object.  Better, yet, change it to apply the handler to the object unobtrusively: http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/

```
$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
   alert("test");   
});
```

Note applying the handler this way, instead of inline, keeps your HTML clean.  I'm using jQuery, but you could do it with or without a framework or using a different framework, if you like.

Comment: @Innuendo - jsFiddle uses separate frames for code/html/style sheets.  you'd need to reference the frame in the function call, but there isn't really an easy way to do that since the frame doesn't have a name.  It's really a problem because of the way jsfiddle works, but it's still a good idea to keep your javascript completely separate.

Comment: @tvanfosson- your solution works, but jsfiddle doesn't use separate frames to show the result; see http://jsfiddle.net/Yazpj/show/.  The reason it didn't work initially is that `test` was defined inside of an `onLoad` function; using `window.test = function(){/*...*/}` makes it work perfectly well.

Comment: @ellisbben - if I use Firebug to inspect the DOM, each of the 4 separate panes exists in a separate iframe.

Comment: Yes, but if you examine the single iframe used to show the example, you'll see that it puts all of the code in a single page that does not use frames, hence those frames cannot break your example.  Append `show` to any jsfiddle URL to see what I'm talking about: jsfiddle.net/Yazpj/show

Answer (score 101):

If you do not specify the wrap setting it defaults to "onLoad". This results with all JavaScript being wrapped in a function run after result has been loaded. All variables are local to this function thus unavailable in the global scope.

Change the wrapping setting to "no wrap" and it'll work:

http://jsfiddle.net/zalun/Yazpj/1/

I switched the framework to "No Library" as you don't use any.

Answer (score 22):

There is another way, declare your function into a variable like this :

```
test = function() {
  alert("test");
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yazpj/2631/)

---

### Details

**EDIT (based on the comments of @nnnnnn)**

*@nnnnnn :*

> why saying `test =` (without `var`) would fix it ?

When you define a function like this :

```
var test = function(){};
```

The function is defined locally, but when you define your function without `var` :

```
test = function(){};
```

`test` is defined on the `window` object which is at the top level scope.

> why does this work?

Like @zalun say :

> If you do not specify the wrap setting it defaults to "onLoad". This results with all JavaScript being wrapped in a function run after result has been loaded. All variables are local to this function thus unavailable in the global scope.

But if you use this syntax :

```
test = function(){};
```

You have an access to the function `test` because it's defined globally

---

*References :*

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/338053/3083093
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5830423/3083093

Comment: This is really the simplest approach is you're just testing a tiny bit of code in JSFiddle.

Comment: But *why* does this work? The "More information" link you provided doesn't explain that the problem is related to scope, or why saying `test = ` (without `var`) would fix it.

Comment: @R3tep well your first link which is : http://jsfiddle.net/R3tep/Yazpj/1406/  alert doesn't do anything for me. I'm on chrome.

Comment: @R3tep yeah it works with console.log. I'll post a question on SO because I believe the fact that I've no alert box is linked to another problem I've with iframes.

Comment: @R3tep For info I found out why it doesn't work. Your chrome isn't updated so you might get the problem too in the future when you update. I added allow-modals to the sandbox and it made it work. Keep it in the back of your mind if you happen to have the same problem than me. Cheers.

Comment: @R3tep I think you misunderstood me but I'm not sure. Your code is/was good. There is an issue with how JSFiddle is coded (missing value in sandbox attribute of the iframe they are  using to display the result). That makes it such it won't work on some version of chrome. I sent an issue report on their github. I was that much interested in it because I thought  the issue I'm having on my website was the same but no. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Change wrap setting in the Frameworks & Extensions panel, to "No wrap-in `<body>`"

Answer (score -1):

There is no problem with your code.Just choose the extension onLoad() from right side.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script> 
function test(){
 alert("test");   
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="test" onclick="test()">
```

Answer (score -3):

```
Select OnDomready
```

HTML:

```
<input id="dButton" type="button" value="test"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
addEventListener('load', init, false);

function init()
{
  oInput = document.getElementById('dButton');
  oInput.onclick = test;
}

function test(){
  alert("test");
}
```