# JavaScript not running on jsfiddle.net

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

The code below works on a live site but I can't get it to run on the site [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) .

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/afPrc/) for example.

Can anyone tell me why it's not working on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

On the console it logs: `ReferenceError: fillList is not defined` and `ReferenceError: mySelectList is not defined`.

The code works as you can see when it's embedded here as snippet:

```js
function BetterSelect(oSelList) {
  this.objSelectList = oSelList;
  this.objSelectList.onchange = this.selectionChanged;
}
BetterSelect.prototype.clear = function() {
  this.objSelectList.options.length = 0;
}
BetterSelect.prototype.fill = function(aValues) {
  this.clear();
  for (var i = 0; i < aValues.length; i++) {
    this.objSelectList.options[i] = new Option(aValues[i]);
  }
}
BetterSelect.prototype.find = function(strToFind, bSelect) {
  var indx = -1;
  this.objSelectList.options.selectedIndex = -1;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.getCount(); i++) {
    if (this.objSelectList.options[i].text == strToFind) {
      indx = i;
      if (bSelect)
        this.objSelectList.options.selectedIndex = i;
    }
  }
  return indx;
}
BetterSelect.prototype.getCount = function() {
  return this.objSelectList.options.length;
}
BetterSelect.prototype.selectionChanged = function() {
  alert("selection changed!");
}

var mySelectList = null;
window.onload = function() {
  mySelectList = new BetterSelect(document.getElementById('theList'));
}

function fillList() {
  mySelectList.fill(["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]);
}

function findIt() {
  mySelectList.find(document.getElementById('txtToFind').value, true);
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <select multiple="multiple" name="Select1" id="theList" style="width: 152px; height: 226px">
  </select>
  <br />
  <input name="Button1" type="button" value="Fill The List" onclick="fillList()" />
  <input name="Button4" onclick="mySelectList.clear()" type="button" value="Clear The List" />
  <br />
  <input name="Button2" onclick="alert(mySelectList.getCount())" type="button" value="What's The Count?" />
  <br />
  <input name="Text1" type="text" id="txtToFind" />
  <input name="Button3" type="button" value="Search" onclick="findIt()" />
</form>
```

Comment: see also the possible duplicate [Simple example doesn't work on JSFiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/simple-example-doesnt-work-on-jsfiddle)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The functions you define are defined in an onload function, so whereas before they were referenceable, because they are defined in that function they can only be referenced from within that function. You reference them as globals in your HTML. You have three options

a) ( easiest, quickest, not ideal ) - change `function blah(){}` to `window.blah = function(){};` making the functions global.

b) ( ideal way ) - use unobtrusive Javascript to attach behaviour to DOM elements from within the JS solely, meaning separate HTML from JS.

c) Make the jsfiddle not wrap the stuff onload. Change `onLoad` to no wrap ( body or head ).

So instead of `<p onclick="lol()" id="foo">` you'd do `var e = document.getElementById('foo'); e.onclick = lol;` in the JS only.

I recommend b as it encourages best practices.

Comment: thank you. how is it then that the code works on a live site?

Comment: Because the functions are not defined within another function on the live site. The jsfiddle throws your JS inside a function. View source on http://fiddle.jshell.net/mjmitche/afPrc/show/

Comment: Thanks.  It's pretty absurd that this workaround is required, though.

Answer (score 49):

In your fiddle select `no wrap (head)` in the dropdown on the left, click Run and it will work.

[**See example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/afPrc/1/)

When `onLoad` is selected your functions are defined within the closure of the `$(document).ready(function() {});` only.

Comment: Nowrap is good option unless you're trying to read cookies from the session.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any nowrap option any more, even though it's still mentioned in the docs (which appear to be out of date).

Comment: It's still there.  It's in the settings dropdown for the Javascript pane.

Answer (score 6):

I found the same issue and solve it by changing `Load Type` in the JavaScript settings:

`No wrap-in<head>` or `No wrap-in<body>` in the drop down JavaScript settings menu. Refer the below image.

[JavaScript Settings Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQXvn.png)

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any javascript menu any more.

Comment: @CpnCrunch No. The menu is still there in the top right corner of JavaScript code section.

Comment: Ok thanks, you're right. I was looking at the top and left of the window. I never expected a menu option to be in one of the child windows.

Answer (score 0):

Look at:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4935684/6796393

Or it is better to see this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19110630/6796393

Here is what I tested:

```
function testJSON() { 
    var jsonString = '{"param1":"123","param2":"XXX78","param3":"11378"}'; 
    var tmp_obj = eval('(' + jsonString + ')');
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =  tmp_obj.param2;
}
```

and

```
function testJSON() { 
    var jsonString = '{"param1":"123","param2":"XXX78","param3":"11378"}'; 
    var tmp_obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =  tmp_obj.param2;
}
```

It is better to use the second aproach.

P.S.> I came from [How to parse parameters from JSON String using JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40206181/6796393)