# Jquery/JS - Function not defined

Tags: jquery, function, defined

can anybody tell me why i get the error "translater is not defined" ?

working example
http://jsfiddle.net/PkqKg/7/

I am confused.Thanks in advance!
Peter

Comment: duplicate of [JavaScript not running on jsfiddle.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468350/javascript-not-running-on-jsfiddle-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsfiddle runs the contents of the Javascript box inside a closure, so your variables cannot be accessod globally. You can do this if you want

```
window.translater = function() {.. }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply change it to no wrap(head or body)
http://jsfiddle.net/PkqKg/9/

Answer (score 0):

or you can use as well like this :

http://jsfiddle.net/corotchi/PkqKg/10/