# why does is say - underscore is undefined

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Why does is say - '_' is undefined, below is a basic simple example and a fiddle. thank you

http://jsfiddle.net/fuEfq/

```
-------------index.html---------------------------
<html>
<head>

    <title></title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="underscore.js"></script>     
        <script type="text/javascript" src="myJs.js"></script>   

    <head>  

    <html>

    <body>


    <script>

    <button type="button" onclick = "loadThis();">Click Me!</button>



    </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

---

```
-------------myJs.js---------------------------


var loadThis = function(){

    vas x = _.uniq([1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4]);

    alert(x);

};
```

Comment: The example code in the JS Fiddle does not give the same error as you describe in the question. Please provide an example that accurately reflects your problem.

Comment: Your fiddle cannot find `loadThis` because you've selected the option to load JavaScript in an onLoad handler and it's defined as local variable. If you fix that, it works as expected. The obvious suspect is that `underscore.js` is not loading. All modern browsers have tools to verify that.

Comment: Are you sure the `underscore.js` script was loaded correctly from you page? Check the error console.

Comment: See also the possible duplicate [JavaScript not running on jsfiddle.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468350/javascript-not-running-on-jsfiddle-net) if your question is just about the fiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your fiddle is that `loadThis` is contained within a function that jsFiddle provides for you (wrapping your code), and the error is that `loadThis`, not `_`, is undefined. (If you look on the left, you'll see you have "onLoad" in the second drop-down selected. This means that jsFiddle generates a `window.load` callback for you and puts your code in that callback.) If I fix that with [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fuEfq/4/), it works fine.

If you're seeing an error in your real code saying `_` is undefined, that suggests you haven't (successfully) loaded underscore.js. This would typically be because you didn't put the `script` tag for it in, the `script` tag was misformed in some way, or the URL in the tag was wrong. If you look in the JavaScript console of your browser (if your browser doesn't have one, switch to a modern browser, which will), which will show you if the URL is wrong.