# Function doesn't execute from an onclick inside the html

Tags: javascript, html, dom, onclick

this is probably stupidly easy but I'm very new to JavaScript and it's driving me nuts.

My question, why doesn't this work: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Ye9tG/

```
<input type="button" id="butt" value="Button" onclick="getThought();"/>
```

It works fine if I add the onclick directly into the JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("butt").onclick = getThought;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here it works now: http://jsfiddle.net/sJ9pF/
I just added the function into the dead.

Comment: See this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5468370/2926151, and this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5830423/2926151

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `getThoughts` function isn't defined, because your JavaScript is set to execute `onLoad`. See the dropdown menu in the upper left of jsFiddle. Select "No wrap - in `<head>`" to resolve the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/Ye9tG/1/

Also, always take a look at your browser's console to check for errors. In this case, you'll see a `Uncaught ReferenceError: getThought is not defined` error when clicking the button.

Comment: Thanks, thought it would be something silly. Didn't even think about the possibility if it being jsFiddle rather than the code itself.

Comment: @user2999861: No problem - happy to help. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 2):

In the top left corner of jsfiddle you'll see that your fiddle is set to run your js code "onLoad".  What that really means is that jsfiddle creates this for you:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){

// YOUR CODE HERE

}//]]>  

</script>
```

As a result, your function is only accessible within that `onload` function.  Change the value to "no wrap head" and you'll see that it works.

Your other option would be to make your function explicitly global:

```
window.getThought = function(){
  // ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ye9tG/5/