# radio button in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I am trying to get the selected value from the radio button [this](http://jsfiddle.net/meetantoalphi/9WX3D/) is the jsfiddle.

HTML :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> Is Reference Number Available</td>
         <td> <input type="radio" name="group1" value="yes" onchange="isReferenceNumberAvailable()"> Yes</input> 
              <input type="radio" name="group1" value="no" onchange="isReferenceNumberAvailable()"> No </input>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

javascript :

```
function isReferenceNumberAvailable()
{    
        var test = document.getElementsByName("group1");

        for(var elem in test)
        {
            if(test[elem].checked)
            {
                alert(test[elem].value);  // got the element which is checked      
                if(test[elem].value=="yes")
                    alert("Need to create Reference select box");
                else if(test[elem].value=="no")
                    alert("don't create ");      
            }
        }
}
```

But when I select the radio button i get the following :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: isReferenceNumberAvailable is not defined
```

Comment: You need to select the "No wrap - in `<head>`" option from the dropdown on the left: http://jsfiddle.net/9WX3D/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function doesn't execute from an onclick inside the html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021628/function-doesnt-execute-from-an-onclick-inside-the-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this

http://jsfiddle.net/9JQU6/

```
function isReferenceNumberAvailable()
{    
        var test = document.getElementsByName("group1");

        for(var elem in test)
        {
            if(test[elem].checked)
            {
                alert(test[elem].value);  // got the element which is checked      
                if(test[elem].value=="yes")
                    alert("Need to create Reference select box");
                else if(test[elem].value=="no")
                    alert("don't create ");      
            }
        }
}
```

Reason

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working only error is `javascript place error` see this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9WX3D/3/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is only that its not getting linked in fiddle, it works when placed inside script tags within your HTML see [Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/9WX3D/4/)

```
<script> Within this together with html its fine </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following script using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input:radio').click(function(){
alert$('input[name=group1]:checked').val()); // get selected radio button value
// do what you need here
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/anAyIWUN/1/edit

<sup>**Try always to put all your JS before the closing `</body>` tag.**</sup>

Regarding your HTML and scripts I would go with something nicer and simpler:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> Is Reference Number Available</td>
         <td>
           <input type="radio" name="group1" value="yes"> Yes
           <input type="radio" name="group1" value="no"> No 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var $el = document.getElementsByName("group1"),
    msg = {"yes":"Need to create Reference select box", "no":"Don't create"};

function getVal(){    
   if(this.checked) alert( msg[this.value] );
}

for(var i=0; i<$el.length; i++)
    $el[i].onchange = getVal;
```