# Call a javascrtipt after button click

Tags: javascript, html

I need to call a JavaScript after pressing a button with type button.

```
<button type='button' 
        class='btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right m-t-n-xs' 
        style='width: 100%;' id='demo' onclick='demo();'>
          <strong>Edit</strong>
</button>
```

I've tried the JavaScript below but it has errors

```
 $('#demo').click(function() {
     alert('hey');
 });
```

For the JS above, it doesn't have an error but it doesn't alert..

```
document.getElementById("demo").onclick = function() { myFunction() };

function myFunction() {
    alert('hey');
}
```

The error for the js above is : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null at HTMLDocument.

```
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById("demo").onclick=function() {
     alert("Hello WOrld");
    }
}
```

The error for this last one is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null 
> at window.onload

Comment: you need a function called `demo` (it is currently missing from your js section)

Comment: read your html tag, the part where you set `onclick='demo();'`

Comment: Possibly also relevant:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021628/function-doesnt-execute-from-an-onclick-inside-the-html

Comment: To get better help, please click the edit link below your post and include the exact error messages you are seeing.

Comment: @Paul, there I put the error messages..

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('#demo').click(function() {
     console.log('hey');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right m-t-n-xs' style='width: 100%;' id='demo'>
          <strong>Edit</strong>
</button>
```

Comment: This works in all my browsers. @Domy: Are you sure you're not adding the button dynamically... after the document  ready happened?

Answer (score 1):

I have removed the irrelevant parts of you code to simplify the answer. Here is a simpler HTML:

```
<button id="demo">Edit</button>
```

Note that *you should not include JavaScript in the `onclick` attribute*. That’s old school, and will only make your life more miserable.

Here is some sample JavaScript:

```
window.onload=function() {
    var button=document.querySelector('button#demo');
    button.onclick=doit;
}

function doit() {
    alert('clicked');
}
```

You certainly don’t need jQuery for this sort of thing.

For what it’s worth, you probably shouldn’t be using the `style` attribute either — that’s what the `class` attribute is there for. Also don’t use `strong` inside the button. It is semantically incorrect, and, if you want to text to be bold, use CSS on the button itself.

Comment: It still doesn't work.. possibly because the button type is button?

Comment: It still doesn't work.. possibly because the button type is button?

Comment: No, you’re correct — I made a couple of typos. The `id` in the `button` element was wrong, and the string in the JavaScript didn’t match. I have also changed the name of the function for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete example:
    button is created with button type and onclick function is bonded.
    `<button type="button" onclick="onClickHandler()">Click Me!</button>`

```
`<script>
    // This function gets triggered when button is clicked.
    function onClickHandler(){
        alert("JS rocks");
    }
</script>`
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanations why this code snippet answers the question.