# Simple function not working in Chrome and Chromium

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, user-interface

This simple piece of chode is not working in Chromium(Ubunto) and Chrome.

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="saveFavPunch" name="saveFavPunch" value="save" onClick="saveFavPunch()" >
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var req;
function saveFavPunch(){
    alert('govind singh');
    if(!req){
        req=$.ajax({
            type:"POST",                
            url:"edit?editType=saveFavPunch",
            data: {"value":document.getElementById("punchId").value},
            complete:function(){req=false},
            success: function(data){
                $.fancybox.close();
                if(data==""){
                    alert("ERROR!");
                }else{
                if(data=="0"){
                    alert("Internal Error Occurs, please try after some time");
                }else{
                    document.getElementById("favPunchline").innerHTML=data;
                }
                }                       
            }//end success
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, please provide a better description of what you're trying to do.

Comment: is there anything wrong in above piece of code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YEPm3/11/ check this out.

Comment: There's is nothing wrong with the code you posted. It's something else. Since it's a simple example, you probably should post the entire code.

Comment: i think onClick is not working in my code.when i tried @user2806799's solution its works fine.

Comment: I edited my answer with a link to a fiddle with the working ajax call on button click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mentioned jQuery in your tags, I thought I'd give a jQuery solution: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YEPm3/10/)

Html:

```
<input type="button" id="saveFavPunch" name="saveFavPunch" value="save" />
```

Javascript:

```
$("#saveFavPunch").on("click", function () {
    alert('hello2');
});
```

:)

**Edit**

[Javascript Not Running On JSFiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468350/javascript-not-running-on-jsfiddle-net) is a possible duplicate of your question. I am quoting the selected answer:

> The functions you define are defined in an onload function, so whereas before they were referenceable, because they are defined in that function they can only be referenced from within that function. You reference them as globals in your HTML. You have three options
>
> a) ( easiest, quickest, not ideal ) - change function blah(){} to window.blah = function(){}; making the functions global.
>
> b) ( ideal way ) - use unobtrusive Javascript to attach behaviour to DOM elements from within the JS solely, meaning separate HTML from JS.
>
> c) Make the jsfiddle not wrap the stuff onload. Change onLoad to no wrap ( body or head ).
>
> So instead of  you'd do var e = document.getElementById('foo'); e.onclick = lol; in the JS only.
>
> I recommend b as it encourages best practices.

Comment: its helps me. but i still not know the reason why my code is not running

Answer (score 4):

Can't add a comment yet, nothing's wrong with the code, but to make it work in jsfiddle change  onLoad to noWrap

Description of what each of the settings does: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#frameworks-and-extensions

Basically you need it to be in a simple `<script>` tag, not in the `onLoad` event

Fiddle with the code you provided: http://jsfiddle.net/Sam88/YEPm3/12/

Comment: +1 I think this is correct, but I'm getting a 500 Internal Server error from a JSONP call when I switch, so it might be that they're having some server side issues right now.

Comment: @Sam i know my fiddler link is not working properly and the issues is of nowrap, but in my website my ajax call is not called for chrome and chromium users. i want to know reason,and by the way thanks for your work, your link works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Just one change — JSFiddle setting from "onLoad" to "No wrap - in " and it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/3f7PT/

The problem with the onLoad option is that this is what it outputs in the results:

```
//<![CDATA[ 
    window.onload=function(){
        function saveFavPunch(){
            alert('hello2');
        }
}//]]>
```

So your function gets unintentionally wrapped in another function which stops it being found from that `onclick` call.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The following entire script works properly in Chrome for me.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function saveFavPunch(){
    alert('hello2');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="saveFavPunch" name="saveFavPunch" value="save" onClick="saveFavPunch()" >
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
document.getElementById("saveFavPunch").addEventListener("click", saveFavPunch);
function saveFavPunch(){
    alert('hello2');

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6sg9R/

Answer (score 0):

Ye JSFiddle is very finicky about Alerts. It works no problem as Spassvogel shows but your way should work as well from file as opposed to on JSfiddle.

Answer (score -3):

Even those you having this type of problem then use div tag

```
    <div id="saveFavPunch" style="height:30px; widht:100px; display:block;" onClick="saveFavPunch()">Save</div>
```

I think Using this code Your problem will solve.