# How do I load values into input text fields once the page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Right now I'm trying out the following code, but nothing will appear in any of my input text boxes on page load.

HTML:

```
<body onload="test()">
<input type="text" id="line0"></input>
<br>
<input type="text" id='line1'></input>
<br>
<input type="text" id='line2'></input>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
function test() {
    var value = "test|some|thing";
    var valueArray = value.split("|");
    for (var lineNumber=0; lineNumber < valueArray.size(); lineNumber++) 
    {
        line = "line" + lineNumber;
        document.getElementById(line).value = valueArray[lineNumber];
    }
}
```

JFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mWL9m/1/

In my actual code, I will be bringing in a value from outside the function, but that isn't really important. Right now I'm just using the test value `value`.

I've looked at several different threads, but all seem to be focused on `onclick` rather than `onload`.

Comment: The answer lies here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready

Comment: Your html markup is wonky, input elements and br are self-closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong property to get the size of the array. User **.length** instead of **.size()**.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/u2g2p/1/

```
function test() {
    var value = "test|some|thing";
    var valueArray = value.split("|");
    for (var lineNumber=0; lineNumber < valueArray.length; lineNumber++) 
    {
        line = "line" + lineNumber;
        document.getElementById(line).value = valueArray[lineNumber];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
document.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
    Javascript code goes here
}
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
window.onload = function()
{
    Javascript code goes here
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated your fiddle, here is the code.

```
(function(){ //This replaces the onload by executing the code within this annonymous function once the page loads.
var value = "test|some|thing";  //No edits here
var lineNumber = 0; //No edits here
var valueArray = value.split("|");
for (lineNumber=0; lineNumber < valueArray.length; lineNumber++) { //using .length instead of size and initialized lineNumber again, mostly because I like to keep my initialization in the loop, personal preference.
    var lineid = "line" + lineNumber; // It was missing "var", changed the variable name too
    var currentLine = valueArray[lineNumber];  //same deal
    var inputElem=document.getElementById(lineid); //I get the element before accessing the value property, again, preference mostly
    inputElem.value = currentLine; //same code.
} //End of for loop
})(); //end of the annonymous function
```

Comment: This fixes the issue, but I agree with filoxo, a short explanation would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues with your fiddle. The first is that you should use `length` instead of `size()` to get the length of your array (I don't believe there is a built-in size method for Javascript arrays):

```
for (lineNumber=0; lineNumber < valueArray.length; lineNumber++) {
```

And the second is that because of the declaration scope of your test function, it's not being found on load. Read this:

[JavaScript not running on jsfiddle.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468350/javascript-not-running-on-jsfiddle-net)

And change

```
function test() {
```

To this:

```
window.test = function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

It's .length for the number of objects in an array.

```
/*Javascript*/

function test(){
    var testVal = "test|some|thing";
    testValArr = testVal.split('|');

    for (i = 0; i < testValArr.length; i++) { 

     document.getElementById('line' + i).value = testValArr[i];
  }
}
```