# toggle text area on button click

Tags: javascript, html, button

I want to enable the text area, when I click the toggle button. Once the comments are saved from the text area, it has to hide and return to the old position. Since I'm a newbie, struggling a little. Thanks in advance :-)

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <textarea class="ipText" name="myTextBox" id="txtBox" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
      </br>
      <button type="submit" onclick="saveComment()">Save</button>
      <input type="button" name="enableText" id="enableTxt" value="Click to Toggle" onclick="toggleText();">
      <script type ="text/javascript">
         function toggleText(txt) {
            document.getElementById("txtBox").disabled = !txt.clicked;
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: here is the jfiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/suP8z/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
 function toggleText() {
      var Disabled = document.getElementById("txtBox").disabled;
      document.getElementById("txtBox").disabled = !Disabled;
   }
```

Add javscript in `<head>` tag of your HTML tag.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/d8NMk/

Comment: Try this, in your code/project. I have tried this in jsfiddle, i got error like `toggleText` undefined error.

Comment: REason for Why simple javascript not working in jsfiddle - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468350/javascript-not-running-on-jsfiddle-net

Comment: Thanks Krish !! It's working well in project. Something went wrong with my internet(jfiddle was facing issue).

Answer (score 1):

Can you try :

```
<html>  
<body>
    <textarea class="ipText" name="myTextBox" disabled="disabled" id="txtBox" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
    </br>
    <button type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('txtBox').disabled = true; return false;">Save</button>
    <input type="button" name="enableText" id="enableTxt" value="Click to Toggle" onclick="document.getElementById('txtBox').disabled = false; return false;">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nope it's not working. The jfiddle link too has the same old output.

Comment: @ManivG Try the new code. Also, you can check jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/suP8z/17/

Comment: @ManivG You must appreciate someone's efforts by marking "this answer solved my problem" / "this answer is useful". Final jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/suP8z/17/

Comment: @ManivG How you want it to work? (1) Click on 'click to toggle' (2) it will allow to add comments (3) click on 'Save' and it will disable comment section. Then you can again 'click to toggle' to enable comments edit and save to disable/save comments.

Comment: If jsfiddle isn't working then could you try above updated code? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/24878592/1266584)

Comment: Hi dipak, I went offline for a while and couldn't check that. Thanks, it's disabling. By the way how to hide and show on the button click.

Comment: I tried in my system now, that's working. Something wrong with the jfiddle. Thanks again.

Comment: @ManivG If it's working, can you tick my answer as "solved your question".

Answer (score 1):

By giving your `<textarea>` element the `id` `txtBox`, we can easily capture it using the `document.getElementById` function and negate its `disabled` attribute.

Here's the JavaScript code (goes inside the `<head>` tags):

```
<script>
    function toggleText() {
        var value = document.getElementById("txtBox").disabled;
        document.getElementById("txtBox").disabled = !value;
    };
</script>
```

And the HTML:

```
<body>
    <textarea class="ipText" name="myTextBox" id="txtBox" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
    </br>
    <button type="submit" onclick="saveComment()">Save</button>
    <input type="button" name="enableText" id="enableTxt" value="Click to Toggle" onclick="toggleText();">
</body>
```

Here's a sample jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/suP8z/18/

The full working code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function toggleText() {
        var value = document.getElementById("txtBox").disabled;
        document.getElementById("txtBox").disabled = !value;
     };
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea class="ipText" name="myTextBox" id="txtBox" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
    </br>
    <button type="submit" onclick="saveComment()">Save</button>
    <input type="button" name="enableText" id="enableTxt" value="Click to Toggle" onclick="toggleText();">
</body>
</html>
```