# Delete TABLE row TR with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to delete the TR from the table using JavaScript and I don't know for some reasons when I click on delete button its not deleting the complete TR instead its just deleting the img file.

```
function remove(rowid)  
{   
    var row = document.getElementById(rowid);
    var table = row.parentNode;
    while ( table && table.tagName != 'TABLE' )
        table = table.parentNode;
    if ( !table )
        return;
    table.deleteRow(row.rowIndex);
}
```

Please check the JS Fiddle for reference http://jsfiddle.net/h09wsrox/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do a similar function but to a whole class. It should be similar though. Not sure of your requirements, but I used JQuery to accomplish this.

```
function remove(rowid){
    $("#" + rowid).remove();
}
```

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: Try this one. Note I had to change the settings on the left. http://jsfiddle.net/h09wsrox/23/

Comment: You could also make it have animations like this: http://jsfiddle.net/h09wsrox/24/

Comment: Just remember, when using JQuery, you should use the $(document).ready(function(){  yourjqueryhere  }); http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 4):

```
function removee(rowid)  
{   
    var row1 = document.getElementById(rowid);
    var table1 = row1.parentNode;
    while ( table1.tagName != 'TABLE' )
        table1 = table1.parentNode;
    if ( !table1 )
        return;
    table1.deleteRow(row1.rowIndex);

}
```

I have updated your js function name to `remove` to `removee` and also some small changes in it.

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/h09wsrox/16/)**

JavaScript in separate block [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/h09wsrox/21/)

I hope it helps you.

Comment: The problem is indeed with the identifier `remove`, which is treated as predefined for some reason. Replacing it by any suitable identifier fixes the problem. I would rather use a more natural identifier like `removeRow`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468350/javascript-not-running-on-jsfiddle-net refer this and also check the Demo in my answer