# iFrame not being editable ( wysiwyg javascript )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to get a simple concept of `wysiwyg` editor. And I am stuck at this:

## HTML

```
<iframe name="rte" id="rte" style="border:#000000 1px solid;"></iframe>
<button onclick="makeBold();"><span class="fa fa-bold"></span></button>
```

## Javascript

```
var richTextField = document.getElementById("rte");
richTextField.document.designMode = "On";

function makeBold()
{
    richTextField.document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
}
```

Problem: The iframe is not editable.

## [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7kh6kdet/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
richTextField.document.designMode = "On";
```

To:

```
richTextField.contentDocument.designMode = "On";
```

to make the iframe editable.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.designMode

EDIT: For your second question, change your current function to:

```
window.makeBold = function()
{
    richTextField.contentDocument.execCommand('bold', false, null);
}
```

It is because your function is defined in the onLoad event, and not within the scope of the window. See [JavaScript not running on jsfiddle.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468350/javascript-not-running-on-jsfiddle-net) for a good explanation.

Comment: So now it's editable but bold command is not working can you check that plz?