# Javascript Test for Multiple Selection Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is an edit check on a multiple select field for a search form.

When a selection is made in the multiple select field and the form is submitted, the `empty()` function logs "USER MADE A SELECTION", that part works. However, if no selection is made, the `empty()` function does not log "NO SELECTION MADE". If no selection is made in the field, won't the variables `citySelectedValue` and `citySelectedHTML` be null and/or undefined? I believe the script I found checks for that? Not sure if I setup my jsfiddle correctly. If not, let me know and I'll fix it:

https://jsfiddle.net/ibuprofen/077qxk01/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:
https://jsfiddle.net/077qxk01/31/

This function is rsponsible for getting proper information about selected options. You could even extract their values or text:

```
function getSelectValues(select) {
  var result = [];
  var options = select && select.options;
  var opt;

  for (var i=0, iLen=options.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    opt = options[i];

    if (opt.selected) {
      result.push(opt.value || opt.text);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

As for JSFiddle - i would recommend sticking to this: [JavaScript not running on jsfiddle.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468350/javascript-not-running-on-jsfiddle-net) guidelines when trying to use "onclick" attribute :)

Comment: Well, what you posted works like I thought the other would so I'll go with that. Also read through the link you posted and I'll follow that from now on. Thanks for the help, I can now get back to work.