# ngRoute dependency issue

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

http://jsfiddle.net/4nil/puw6huv4/
Here,
I am trying to inject ngroute dependency

```
var sampleApp = angular.module("sampleApp", ["ngRoute"]);
```

and trying to use routeprovider as below

```
sampleApp.config(["$routeProvider",
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when("/addRomCom", {
    templateUrl: "add_book.html",
    controller: "romcomctrl"
      }).
      when("/addHorror", {
    templateUrl: "add_book.html",
    controller: "horrorctrl"
      }).
      otherwise({
    redirectTo: "/"
      });
}]);
```

The same code works in a standalone application, i have only one html which has script tag which has the code.

Comment: i could not figure out the issue in the fiddle, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your `fiddle` is the loading of your `js`. right now you are loading it in `onLoad`

Go to the `javascript` section settings and change the load type to : `No Wrap in <body>`

**EDIT:**

if you put it on load, the code would be local to the `onLoad` scope, and it would not be visible outside globally, so `ng-app="myApp"` would not be able to recognize the module because

`var myApp = angular.module("myApp", [] ) ;` lives only inside the onLoad function.

Comment: it worked. But what's the difference? onload vs No wrap in <body>

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32206369/jsfiddle-onload-and-and-no-wrap-in-body

Comment: i still could not find out the reason, like all the html dom parsing is done, js are loaded, script is parsed and ready to run. So when 'onload' is used whats the problem and it's giving angular dependency error means it is executing the script code and it's executing it after dom parsing. so question remains why it works with 'NO WRAP'?

Comment: It works with no wrap because the variables are available in global scope now , see edit

Comment: i think you are trying to put it other way, like js code would find the html dom elements not the other way around?

Comment: could you please explain both the cases with flow(steps) like, -1. DOM parsing -2. DOM Rendering -3. Script code execution  and so on?

Comment: Yes, you can try writing your code in onload , the var myApp won't be visible to ng-app because it would be inside a anonymous function

Comment: ask a separate question for that... more people will reply, maybe somebody else can explain it bettr