# What specifically will successfully trigger a JavaScript click event in JSFiddle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle

I was toying around with trying to get events-on-button-click to work where the JavaScript code triggers some event once a specific button is clicked.

There are no issues when I attempt to do on-click triggers in my project(s), but I just can't seem to get it to work using JSFiddle.

I first followed the tips here: [JavaScript not running on jsfiddle.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468350/javascript-not-running-on-jsfiddle-net)

Specifically, the part where meder omuraliev writes, "So instead of

```
<p onclick="lol()" id="foo">
```

you'd do

```
var e = document.getElementById('foo'); 
e.onclick = lol;
```

in the JS only."

I attempted to follow this instruction which can be seen in the simple example I made here (that doesn't work): https://jsfiddle.net/b7yj3cph/3/

```js
var e = document.getElementById('test');
e.onclick = example;

var example = function( {
    alert("hello");
});
```

```html
<button id='test' type="button" onclick="example()">
  <div>
  Hello
  </div>
```

---

I tried other sources and methods but couldn't get any to work. I attempted an example from W3Schools (https://jsfiddle.net/b7yj3cph/) and tried some JSFiddles from searching "jsfiddle button onclick" (https://jsfiddle.net/Dogbyte/62cd0LLq/) which some didn't work.

But some did; like this one (http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/h4JXs/1/) seems to work fine.

What is uniquely going on that makes the click trigger work for some JSFiddles and not for others? I suspect it has to do with the `$(document).ready()` part but I've been reading various ways to get this to work and I can't find anything that makes sense to me.

---

Going back to the Stack Overflow thread that I shared earlier, the top-voted response there had 3 suggestions:

1. *"( easiest, quickest, not ideal ) - change function blah(){} to window.blah = function(){}; making the functions global."*

Well, in the JSFiddle posted here that works as expected, there is no use of `window`. Attempts that I made to use `window` proved to be fruitless.

2. *"( ideal way ) - use unobtrusive Javascript to attach behaviour to DOM elements from within the JS solely, meaning separate HTML from
   JS."*

This is a great point and makes sense but still didn't solve my particular 
issue.

3. *"Make the jsfiddle not wrap the stuff onload. Change `onLoad` to no wrap ( body or head )."*

My particular example isn't wrapped in `onLoad`(at least, I don't think that it is). Anyways, thanks!

Comment: Why the down vote? I'd appreciate knowing what's wrong with my question, thank you.

Comment: even better: use modern event handling. Not 1998 deprecated event handling. In your JS, use `var thing = document.querySelector('...')` to get the element that needs a click handler, then give it one with `thing.addEventListener("click", function(evt) { ... });`

Comment: It'll work if you fix the syntax errors and define the function before you use it. https://jsfiddle.net/b7yj3cph/4/ And yes, your jsfiddle is wrapped in onload (click on the JavaScript gear button).

Comment: This is the right way to do it if you are using vanilla javascript : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/b7yj3cph/6/. Your other posted example uses jquery which different syntax and implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is the way](http://jsfiddle.net/h0z5qqoa/) if you don't want to wait for the DOM to be loaded.

```
document.getElementById('btnSave').addEventListener('click',() => {
    alert('clicked the damn button!');
});
```

The reason attaching something to .onclick doesn't work is because, for that, you do have to wait for the DOM to load; order of operations is really important in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your example + included explanation; I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues in your fiddle:

Firstly your `example` function is declared incorrectly:

```
var e = document.getElementById('test');
e.onclick = example;

var example = function( { // parenthasis should be closed before opening braces
    alert("hello");
});
```

Should be:

```
var e = document.getElementById('test');
e.onclick = example;

var example = function() {
    alert("hello");
}
```

Secondly, you are declaring the `var example` below the onclick assignment which is being interpreted as:

```
e.onclick = undefined
```

Just move the `var example` above the `e.onclick` and fix the syntax issue and it will work:

```
var e = document.getElementById('test');
var example = function() {
    alert("hello");
}
e.onclick = example;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for finding my issue and fixing it!