# How to parse parameters from JSON String using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to parse a JSON String , but the parsed value is undefined . Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q080hxp3/1/)

```
    <input type="submit" onclick=testJSON() value="Test"/> 
    <div id = "result">Test </div> 

<script> 
    function testJSON() { 

    var jsonString = '{"param1":"123","param2":"XXX78","param3":"11378"}'; 

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (JSON.parse(jsonString)).param2;

    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/q080hxp3/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is working fine - the problem here is in JSFiddle, as it's set to just run the JS code when the document is loaded, so the function doesn't get registered - here's the relevant option:

[image]

Comment: @john We have a winner, this is just the solution

Comment: Not really, this is a comment, or at best a duplicate of the many, many similar questions.