# What happens if you put an iteration count of a for loop as a variable?

Tags: javascript

I want to make a program in javascript in which a person inputted the iteration count for a for loop(they could input x++, or y--), but I don't know if I am using the right method.

Here is my code:

```
   var x = prompt("iteration count")
   // x should equal something like, i++, or x--
   for(var i = 0; i < 10; x){
        document.write(i)
   }
```

But when the code ran the program kept crashing.
Why is it crashing and how do I fix this?
 Please Help

Comment: You need to increment x if you intend to write numbers from 0 to 9. Replace x with x++ in the for loop

Comment: @AbhiraamEranti: Do have a look at my answer, i believe it's what you're looking for

Comment: `for(var i = 0; i < 10, x)` This isn't even syntactically valid; there should be two semicolons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to parse the `int` value of `x` because it's a `string` and use it to increment `i`

```js
var x = parseInt(prompt("iteration count"))

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += x) {
  document.write(i)
}
```

**EDIT :**

based on the question edit and the comments, you can use [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), but :

> **Do not ever use eval!**
>
> eval() is a dangerous function, which executes the code it's passed with the privileges of the caller.

So before you use it, read the MDN page and check : [eval isnt evil it's just misunderstood](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/)

where there's this comment from **Spudley** :

> From a security perspective, eval() is far more dangerous in a server
>   environment, where code is expected to be fully trusted and hidden
>   from the end user.
>
> In a browser, the user could eval any code they wanted at any time
>   simply by opening dev tools, so as a developer you can't get away with
>   having anything on your client code that could be insecure against
>   eval anyway.

to test the snippet below, type `i++` in the `prompt`

```js
var x = prompt("iteration count");

for (var i = 0; i < 10; eval(x)) {
  console.log(i)
}
```

an alternative to `eval()` would be [new Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) or check the answers here : [Programatically setting third statement of for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094172/programatically-setting-third-statement-of-for-loop)

Comment: As requested, `// x should equal something like, i++, or x--` your code doesnt meet this criteria

Comment: @Isaac the question was edited after this answer, i edited it accordingly

Comment: Noted. downvote removed. As for the `new Function` part if you wished to know maybe can refer to my answer

Comment: @Isaac ah i see, i didn't see your answer but maybe you would like to add a link to MDN and some description ( as it is a form of `eval()` )

Answer (score 0):

```js
  
var input = 'i++';//Or whatever condition user passing in
var conditionProgramatically = () => new Function(input)() ;

for (var i = 0; i < 10; conditionProgramatically()) {
  console.log(i)
}
```

For `for-loop`, `third statement` will be invoked/executed on every iteration, and hence we set a function call, and in that function, we execute whatever user passing in as you've mentioned `i++`

Comment: not me but probably related to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094172/programatically-setting-third-statement-of-for-loop

Comment: @Taki: What do you mean in exact because I was the person who posted the question lol

Comment: @Taki: hmmm true. Weird enough that it works here, you can try "Run code snippet" but not on `JSFiddle`. Let me try to check see if manage to find out the difference

Comment: here `var input = 'i++';` the `input` is harcoded but in the fiddle the `input` is read from the `prompt`

Comment: @Taki: I tried to hardcode `var input = 'i++'` at your `fiddle`, doesnt work too.

Comment: Your code doesn't work with a local `i` variable - functions created by `Function` close over the global scope only. Also you should simplify (and optimise) to `conditionProgramatically = new Function(input)`

Comment: @Bergi: But how to explain that running the code snippet here giving the expected result. Aren't they using the exact same JS Engine depending on browser?

Comment: @Isaac [jsFiddle code by default does not run in a global script context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5468350/1048572)

Answer (score -1):

That is an endless loop because the variable i never incremented. Try this one.

```
var x = prompt("iteration count")
for(var i = 0; i < x, i++){
    document.write(i)
}
```

Comment: what i wanted is that you could change the i++, like answering i-- and it will subtract by 1 or i *= 2 and it could change the multiplication value

Comment: sorry for the mislead

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to increment the index variable, it result to endless loop and maximum stack error, you can also use + for parseInt shorcut.

```
 var x = +prompt("iteration count")
 for(var i = 0; i < x;i++){
    document.write(i)
 }
```

Comment: what i wanted is that you could change the i++, like answering i-- and it will subtract by 1 or i *= 2 and it could change the multiplication value

Comment: sorry for the mislead

Answer (score -1):

You have to parse the input value and then make it as a condition to stop iterating after the given value.

```js
var x = parseInt(prompt("iteration count"))

for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  document.write(i);
}
```

Comment: what i wanted is that you could change the i++, like answering i-- and it will subtract by 1 or i *= 2 and it could change the multiplication value

Comment: sorry about the mislead