# Programmatically setting third statement of for loop

Tags: javascript

Wondering if there is by any chance to programmatically setting third statement of forloop

```
var conditionProgrammatically = 'i++';//or 'x--'

for (var i = 0; i < 10; conditionProgrammatically) {
  console.log(i)
}
```

Comment: @Arvind: Yes, sorry for the typo.

Comment: if it's a case of adding 1 or subtracting 1 ... do you know that `i += (-1)` is `--i` and `i += (1)` is `++i`

Comment: I guess the question is, what is the range of possibilities you'd need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use any expression you want there including calling a function. You just need to be careful of scope. So, for example, this works:

```js
var conditionProgramatically = () => i++ ;

for (var i = 0; i < 10; conditionProgramatically()) {
  console.log(i)
}
```

But it depends on the fact that `var i` is in a scope shared by the function. This, however, **doesn't work**:

```js
var conditionProgramatically = () => i++ ;

for (let i = 0; i < 10; conditionProgramatically()) {
  console.log(i)
}
```

Because `let` is scoped to the block and not available.

Of course you can share an object which is mutable by passing it as an argument like:

```js
fn = (o) => o.i += 1
for (let o = {i:0}; o.i < 10; fn(o)) {
    console.log(o.i)
  }
```

This allows you to use `let`, but is a little hard on the eyes.

All said, it's probably going to be easier to make your logic fit in a simple expression rather than calling a function. You can still perform some logic, though:

```js
for (let i = 0; Math.abs(i) < 10; i = Math.random() > .65  ? i -1: i + 1) {
  console.log(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a variable and then operate with this variable according to your needs.
(remember that `i--` is equivalent to `i -= 1`).
BTW, be careful because you would also have to change the condition, if not you will end up in an infinite loop. In your case, I would use `abs()`

```
var step = 1; // or var step = -1;
for (var i = 0; abs(i) < 10; i += step) {
  console.log(i)
}
```

Comment: How is this different to the example in the question?

Comment: `conditionProgramatically` holds a string value on the question. :)

Comment: The difference is that you are not using text (that would have to be analyzed with eval or other unsafe method) but a (much easier to handle) variable.

Comment: If you think this is the same code as in the question, perhaps you need a refresher course in javascript

Answer (score 1):

Usually, in functional programmings (like python and javascript), we can use dictionary (or objects) to store functions.

```
var myFunctions = {
  "a": function (i) { return i + 1 },
  "b": function (i) { return i - 3 }
};
```

Then, we can set the condition as the key to the dictionary:

```
myCondition = "a"; // this will set condition to increment by 1
```

Here is your for loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i = myFunctions[myCondition](i)) {
  // whatever
}
```