# Javascript toggle menu displays unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I have a menu which is hidden by default and should display after clicking on a button - no problem.

The problem starts when I want to hide the menu again - when I hide it by clicking away on the page, it's ok. However, when I want to hide it by clicking on the yellow button, it hides but after clicking on *Normal text* it displays again. I don't know the reason but that's certainly something I don't want.

```
function zobrazSkryVseobecne(idecko) {
    var miesto = document.getElementById(idecko);
    miesto.className = (miesto.className === "skryt" ? "" : "skryt");
}
```

Here's my whole code: https://jsfiddle.net/tu958pwg/

Thanks in advance for any advice and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I cannot see a yellow button.

Comment: Sorry, now it's yellow [link](https://jsfiddle.net/hd14ge6k/1/)

Comment: Also your jsfiddle isn't working because jsfiddle wraps your code in an onload function. See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468350/javascript-not-running-on-jsfiddle-net

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, I have found that the problem is in `onfocusout` event. The main problem I think it is that you are using that event in a not allowed element
Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocusout.asp) info about `onfocusout` event and the elements where you can use it.

I know this is not a solution, but a guide for you to think about the solution yourself.

Let me know if I can help you in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you click on the `menu` button once (show the dropdown), then again (hide the dropdown), the `menu` button still has focus. So when you click on "normal text" (or anywhere else in the window) and `menu` loses focus, `onfocusout` fires, which shows the dropdown.

A better approach might be to add and clear an event listener for `onfocusout`:

```
function hideElem() {
  var miesto = document.getElementById('hidden');
  miesto.className = 'skryt';
}


function zobrazSkryVseobecne(idecko) {
  var miesto = document.getElementById(idecko);
  var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
  // If hidden
  if (miesto.className === 'skryt') {
    miesto.className = '';
    menu.addEventListener('focusout', hideElem)
  // Else if shown
  } else {
    miesto.className = 'skryt';
    menu.removeEventListener('focusout', hideElem)
  }
}
```

And be sure to remove `onfocusout="zobrazSkryVseobecne('hidden')"` from your `button`.