# jsFiddle - what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

Quick question for people familiar with jsFiddle: why doesn't [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nc8D8/) run the function when the button is clicked?

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but can't get it working.

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/simple-example-doesnt-work-on-jsfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select the "no wrap (head)" option in the sidebar. Otherwise, your `f()` function gets wrapped up in some `$(function() { /*...*/ });` stuff and is not visible to be set in an `onclick` attribute:

http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/a6rQX/

Answer (score 1):

Under Framework select "no wrap (head)

Click the Run button.

It should now work.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the function with name `f()` local to the onReady function, so it is not available in the global context.

```
onReady(){
    function f(){
        xyz
    }
}
```