# alert message does not pop up

Tags: javascript, alert

I have put the  code on jsfiddle.net. 
The problem I am having is that the function does not seem to get called when showToast button is clicked.

The actual code
`<button type="button" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')">Show Toast</button><br/`>

```
function showAndroidToast(name){      
        alert("hi");
}
```

I got the error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: showAndroidToast;

Anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: You should put the relevant code directly inside your question, regardless of the jsfiddle link. That way if the link dies, the code is still here.

Comment: i am not able to find any buttons in above code!!!

Comment: @buch11 I changed it. Sorry I had a old reference link of jsfiddle up

Comment: Is the function defined inside of `script` tags?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/simple-example-doesnt-work-on-jsfiddle

The reason behind is because it is handled differently.

Comment: I tried both ways. external js, and within the script. Not working

Comment: correction: I tried inline. works. But I still want to incorporate that into an external js though <br/>
`<script type="text/javascript">
       function showAndroidToast(toast){
         Android.showToast(toast);
    }
      </script>`

Comment: sammiwei -- your js is fine (except check the capitalization of onclick). The problem is that you're using jsfiddle. @cherhan shows the issue in his comment. Moral of the story: real JS developers should not use jsfiddle or similar.

Comment: Mystery Issues. Today it worked. Dont know why..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it is not onClick but onclick, and your function should be declared in some cases like this:

```
<script>
 window.showAndroidToast = function(){
 //code
};
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="window.showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')">
    Show Toast
</button>
```

This is just to be found globally, just to be sure it is not a problem with the browser itself.

Comment: I have reedited to what it should work. If this fails i have no ideea.

Answer (score 0):

Remove type from your button tag:

```
<button onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')">Show Toast</button><br/>
//and check
```

Hope it helps

Comment: could you rename the function name to something else and check once..!

Comment: is your function defined inside script tag...?

Comment: I did, I renamed to a single word 's', and changed to onclick too but it doesn't work