# Changing position of overlapping Canvases

Tags: html, canvas, onclick

I have layered 4 canvases over the top of each over, however i want to be able to click a button and the linked canvas will come to the top.

http://jsfiddle.net/5g3Fe/ shows what i have currently got. I tried to put the following code into the button click functions. however this doesn't work.

```
function canvasView1()
{
document.getElementById("canvas1").style.z-index="1";
document.getElementById("canvas2").style.z-index="0";
document.getElementById("canvas3").style.z-index="0";
document.getElementById("canvas4").style.z-index="0";

}
```

can anyone suggest a way to be able to get specific canvas from a button click.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, jsFiddle was ignoring your JavaScript code because of [this reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/simple-example-doesnt-work-on-jsfiddle). You can get around that by choosing `No wrap - in <body>` on the left hand side options.

Then your problem was that to set the z-index in javascript you use `.style.zIndex` rather than `.style.z-index`.

[Working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5g3Fe/4/)

Or [cleaner code version here](http://jsfiddle.net/5g3Fe/3/)