# href="javascript:proDoc(....can't work on chrome but IE

Tags: javascript

I want to ask 2 questions.

1. How to use http://jsfiddle.net/?
   "Word DownLoad1" is not work in jsfiddle.net???
2. "Word DownLoad2" is work in IE, but it is not work in chrome.Why?
   html.

   ```
   <span id="GridView1_ctl04_lblWord">
     <select name='selPdf56' class='selectMenu'>
       <option value='g38'>A Form</option>
       <option value='g39'>B Form</option>
     </select>
   </span><a id="GridView1_ctl04_lnkWord" href="javascript:proDoc('56','g38');">Word DownLoad1</a> <a id="GridView1_ctl05" href="javascript:proDoc(56,document.getElementById('selPdf56').options[document.getElementById('selPdf56').selectedIndex].value);">Word DownLoad2</a>
   ```

js

```
function proDoc(myDEID,myForm){
       alert('Active');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3pZ2M/7/

Comment: In jsfiddle, Change the wrapping setting to "no wrap"

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/simple-example-doesnt-work-on-jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you did not use an id `selPdf56` but there was `name` and `class` and you used `getElementById` that's why it didn't work and in the `jsFiddle` you chose to run the script `onload` but you should have chosen to keep it in the `head` tags.

**HTML**

```
<span id="GridView1_ctl04_lblWord">
    <select name='selPdf56' id='selPdf56'  class='selectMenu'>
        <option value='g38' >A Form</option>
        <option value='g39' >B Form</option></select>
</span>
<a id="GridView1_ctl04_lnkWord" href="javascript:proDoc('56','g38');">Word DownLoad1</a>
<a id="GridView1_ctl05" href="javascript:proDoc(56,document.getElementById('selPdf56').options[document.getElementById('selPdf56').selectedIndex].value);">Word DownLoad2</a>
```

**JS**

```
function proDoc(myDEID,myForm){
   alert(myDEID +' '+ myForm);
}
```

[**WORKING DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/3pZ2M/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Chrome:

```
 <span id="GridView1_ctl04_lblWord">
 <select id='selPdf56'  class='selectMenu'>
     <option value='g38' >A Form</option>
     <option value='g39' >B Form</option>
 </select></span>
<a id="GridView1_ctl04_lnkWord" href="javascript:proDoc('56','g38');">Word DownLoad1</a>
<a id="GridView1_ctl05"  href="javascript:proDoc(56,document.getElementById('selPdf56').options[document.getElementById('selPdf56').selectedIndex].value);">Word DownLoad2</a>
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3pZ2M/9/