# Why won't this fiddle work?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

It's very basic, but it's not working.  I know I must be missing something really obvious.

Here is the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/NWWL4/

```
<input type="button" onclick='clicked();' value='Click Me!'></input>

function clicked() {
    alert('test');
}
```

Comment: exact duplicate of [Simple example doesn't work on JSFiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/simple-example-doesnt-work-on-jsfiddle)

Comment: JS inline code doesn't work in JSFiddle. Also, you shouldn't use it. Declare the function as global if you want use it like this, but it is not proper : http://jsfiddle.net/NWWL4/4/

Answer (score 5):

You have your fiddle executing the JavaScript onload instead of in the head of the document.

Comment: @user2479733 Just change "No Wrap in <head>" in the left menu : http://jsfiddle.net/NWWL4/7/

Answer (score 1):

try changing

```
function clicked() {
    alert('test');
}
```

to

```
clicked = function() {
    alert('test');
}
```