# jQuery test for an input value fails

Tags: jquery, validation, input

I'm working with the following HTML

```
Level 1: <input type="text" name="benefit_std_level1" maxlength="5" value="0.0" onblur="noSpaceTest();float_5_2_percent(this);" style="width:40px;" class="input nospace">%<br />
Level 2: <input type="text" name="benefit_std_level2" maxlength="5" value="0.0" onblur="noSpaceTest();float_5_2_percent(this);" style="width:40px;" class="input40 nospace">%<br />
Level 3: <input type="text" name="benefit_std_level3" maxlength="5" value="0.0" onblur="noSpaceTest();float_5_2_percent(this);" style="width:40px;" class="input nospace">%<br />
```

There is an error occurring in the database if a user inputs a space into any of the three "Level" fields. I'm therefore employing the following script to check for a space and then change the value back to the default '0.0'.

jQuery:

```
function noSpaceTest(){
    $('.nospace').each(function(){
        if ($('.nospace').val() == ' '){
            $('.nospace').val('0.0');
        }
    });
}
```

Originally, in the site I'm developing, this did work, but only for the first field (onBlur would check and find the space and replace it with 0.0) However, now I can't get it to work in JSFiddle (see link below)

http://jsfiddle.net/pMkYg/

I'm afraid I'm missing something obvious, but I'm not getting any closer to a resolution. Does anyone have any insight they can offer?

Comment: Use [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: Problem in jsfiddle, you cannot use inline script due to how jsfiddle embeded code in iframe, bind events with javascript/jquery . Better explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5431435/1414562

Comment: Okay, well that would explain why it works (partially) on the page I'm coding, but not at all in jsfiddle. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `this` , Also That will fail for multiple spaces like `'    '` -

You can do this -

```
function noSpaceTest(){
    $('.nospace').each(function(){
        if ($.trim(this.value) === ''){
            $(this).val('0.0');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I really like the ability to check for multiples, here -- I did not think of that angle.

Answer (score 4):

remove the inline js and use a `change` event handler instead :

```
$('.nospace').on('change', function () {
    if(/^\s+$/.test(this.value)) this.value = '0.0';
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pMkYg/8/)

Comment: This is a great solution, too.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(this)`:

```
function noSpaceTest(){
    $('.nospace').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.val() == ' '){
            $this.val('0.0');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not very far from working code, here's a fix :

```
function noSpaceTest(){
    $('.nospace').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == ' '){
            $(this).val('0.0');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this for float value

```
    function noSpaceTest() {
        $('.nospace').each(function () {
            var this_input = $(this);
            if (parseFloat(this_input.val()) == undefined || parseFloat(this_input.val()) == NaN || $.trim(this.value) === '') {
                this_input.val('0.0');
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

$(".nospace").blur(function()
                 {

```
    if ($(this).val().trim() == ''){
        $(this).val('0.0');

    }
});
```