# Why this JSFiddle does not work

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I have written a simple function:

```
function clickedMe() {
  alert(this + " : " + this.tagName + " : " + this.id);
}
```

And I am calling it on click event of button element

```
<button onclick="clickedMe()">button</button>
```

This works when I created a standalone HTML page locally. However it does not seem to work on JSFiddle. Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/Mahesha999/fACce/

Whats wrong here?

Comment: The console gives back `ReferenceError: clickedMe is not defined` btw

Comment: Btw similar stuff [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431351/1114320)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select `no wrap - in <head>/<body>` .

It doesn't work because `clickedMe` is not in the global scope.

[image]

Comment: funny enough it seems that this JSFiddle doesnt work with `no wrap` but need `on load`: jsfiddle.net/Mahesha999/fACce/3 Now what if I want both in same JSFiddle?

Comment: We have to wait for the page loaded when we use `addEventLisenter` because `document.getElementById` can not get the element before the dom is ready. http://jsfiddle.net/fACce/5/

Comment: Yeah that I realized but what if I want both buttons one in original question and one in above comments in same JSFiddle, it worked by explicitly including `clickme()` in HTML `<script>` tag [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mahesha999/xKtzC/8/). Though will like to not to have JS in HTML