# Passing element ID to function

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing

I have this function:

```
function op_up(){
    this.style.color=#FF0000;
}
```

And I have this HTML element:

```
<span id="trigger" onClick="op_up(#element_1)">Click to change #element_1<span>
<span id="trigger" onClick="op_up(#element_2)">Click to change #element_2<span>
```

I would like the function to affect the id of the element in the onClick event.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: IDs are strings in JS, there is nothing special about how to pass them to a function. What is your question? Maybe you are looking for `document.getElementById(op_id)`? Or is `other_id` an implicit global variable holding an element with that ID? Then just use `op_id` inside the function instead of `this`. FWIW, `this` wouldn't work either anyway.

Comment: +1 to what @FelixKling mentioned. Except that OP might want to use `document.getElementById(other_id)`.

Comment: I am trying to pass the ID, `other_id`, from the onClick event to the function.

Comment: @AlfredPersonMc: It seems you are already doing that, `op_up(other_id)`. Maybe you have to pass a string instead, `op_up('other_id')`, but it's really not clear form the little explanation you provided. You will likely get better help if you provide a complete example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Ok, I will re-word the question...

Comment: bear in mind that id's must be unique (not the parameter passed, but the element id) - in your HTML, your `span` divs have the same `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function call is not valid, but you can pass a **string** to the function:

```
op_up('#element_1')
```

Then you can use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) to get a reference to the element:

```
function op_up(selector){
    document.querySelector(selector).style.color='#FF0000';
}
```

Or as I already said in the comments, if you pass the ID as

```
op_up('element_1')
```

use `document.getElementById`:

```
function op_up(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.color='#FF0000';
}
```

Comment: Because you didn't setup the fiddle correctly and because the color has to be in a string as well. Copied and pasted your mistakes :P See http://stackoverflow.com/q/17512582/218196

Comment: As I said, either you haven't put the color in a string or you didn't change the jsfiddle to put the function in the head or body. See: http://jsfiddle.net/p9rp6/1/