# Function undefined js

Tags: javascript, html

Why do I get a function undefined http://jsfiddle.net/Arandolph0/8eukN/3/

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<form id="frmcheckbxs" >    
  <c:set var="recordCount" value="2"/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkRefId${recordCount}" onclick="checkRushed    ('frmcheckbxs','chkRefId','2')" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkRefId1" />
</form>
```

I checked and it doesn't look to be something like a typo it appears to be functional.

Comment: Your jsFiddle is set to execute `onLoad`, which means your JavaScript code will be put inside of `window.onload = function () { /* CODE HERE */ };`. Does that look global and available to you?

Comment: duplicate of [Simple example doesn't work on JSFiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/simple-example-doesnt-work-on-jsfiddle)

Answer (score 2):

You have set JSFiddle to wrap all your JavaScript in an onload event handler function.

`checkRushed` is defined inside that function, so it is scoped to that function and not available as a global.

Bind your event handlers with [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) (or the helper function of your choice if you are using a library that abstracts that) instead of using intrinsic event attributes.

Comment: So I've tried this but it only disabled it doesn't re-enable http://jsfiddle.net/Arandolph0/jxjW9/11/

Comment: The event object doesn't have a value, an HTMLInputElement does, so you want to be using `this` not `e`. The value of the input will never be `off` though, you haven't set a value on it. You want to examine the `checked` property, which will be a boolean.

Comment: @AprilRandolph: The `.disabled` property must be set to a boolean! Your strings are both truthy. You probably want something like http://jsfiddle.net/jxjW9/12/

Comment: Also, what do you do when you have a dynamic list of checkboxs that you want to add the eventListener to? Ex. checkbox1, checkbox2, etc....

Comment: Either use a loop, or assign the event handler to an ancestor element and capture it when it bubbles (using `event.target` to figure out which element was hit)

Comment: Umm… the `<form>` itself should do.

Comment: @Quentin In IE the type, when checking, to process an attachEvent is undefined. How do I narrow the element tree to verify/validate my object?