# jQuery sortable only works in document ready, not with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Check out the following jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/PNvvb/1/

I use a sortable div, with items in it. These items are sortable, and use the jQuery UI Sortable plugin. When I instantiate the items in the `document.ready` function, it all works as expected.

But as soon as you click disable, and enable button again, the `sortable` plugin does not work anymore.

This also happens when you just use the buttons, and remove the `sort(true)` from the `document.ready`.

*Why does jQuery UI sortable do work when the DOM hierarchy has been fully constructed, and the ready function is triggered, but does not work when called after this?*

HTML:

```
<div id="sort">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
</div>

<button id="b1">Enable</button>
<button id="b2">Disable</button>
```

CSS:

```
.item {
    display:block;
    background-color: Yellow;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 5px
}

.placeholder { 
    background-color: Green;   
    width: 100px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    sort(true); //Remove this line to see if the enable button works from the start. (which it doesn't)


    //These lines are needed for jsFiddle to get buttons to respond to clicks. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/simple-example-doesnt-work-on-jsfiddle
    $("#b1").click(function() {
        sort(true);
    });
    $("#b2").click(function() {
        sort(false);
    });
});

function sort(enable) {
    if(enable) {
        $("#sort").sortable({ 
            placeholder: "placeholder",
            forcePlaceholderSize: true
        });   
    } else {       
        $("#sort").sortable({ disabled: true });   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not updating the `disabled` property!

```
$("#sort").sortable({ 
    placeholder: "placeholder",
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    disabled: false
});
```

Comment: Yeah... when I posted the question, I found the answer.. ;), Dont you hate that when that happens?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.. found the answer myself:

I just needed to set the disabled back to false!

```
$("#sort").sortable({ 
            placeholder: "placeholder",
            forcePlaceholderSize: true,
            disabled: false
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/h9pB8/)

```
function sort(enable) {

  if(enable) {

    $("#sort").sortable({ 
       placeholder: "placeholder",
       forcePlaceholderSize: true
    });   

  } else {

    $("#sort").sortable({ disabled: true });   

  }

}

$(function() { 

  $("#b1").click(function() {
    $("#sort").sortable({ disabled: false });  
  });
  $("#b2").click(function() {
    $("#sort").sortable({ disabled: true });  
  });

});
```