# How to get jquery sortable to run function on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have some code that will gather up the sort of a sortable list and turn it into an array.  The code is set up to work on the drop event, so when you drag an item and then drop it the array is created and sent out.  I need to change this so that it is triggered by a button click instead, for some reason turning this into a click event will not work though.

Here is the function as it is now

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#sortable-stages').sortable({
     update: function(event, ui) {
         var stage = document.getElementsByClassName('stage');
         var stageOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray');
         $.get('/stages/reorder', { 'order' :  stageOrder });
     }
  });

});
```

Any help on how to turn this code into something that is triggered by a button click would be great.

I did try the obvious

```
$(document).on('click','#stagereorderbutton', function() {
    //...
});
```

and that did not run the code even though it would trigger an alert, but only if placed right at the beginning, above the `update:` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I well understand your question, you should simply get the *array* of sortable items on button `click`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var items = $('#sortable-stages').sortable(/*options...*/);
    $(document).on('click','#stagereorderbutton',function(){
        $.get('/stages/reorder', { 'order' :  items.sortable('toArray') });
    });

});
```

<kbd>[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Lqz478m/)</kbd>

---

And yet another solution if you need the `update` option - you can define an variable outside of the `sortable` scope, update it inside scope and use it on button `click`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var stageOrder;
    $('#sortable-stages').sortable({
        update: function(event, ui) {
            var stage = $('.stage');
            stageOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray');
        }
    });
    $(document).on('click','#stagereorderbutton',function(){
        $.get('/stages/reorder', { 'order' :  stageOrder });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not updating the disabled property, try this

```
$('#stagereorderbutton').sortable({
disabled: false,
     update: function(event, ui) {

     var stage = document.getElementsByClassName('stage');

     var stageOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray');

     $.get('/stages/reorder', { 'order' :  stageOrder });


     }
  });

  });
```

Have you seen this post,
[jQuery sortable only works in document ready, not with a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660699/jquery-sortable-only-works-in-document-ready-not-with-a-button)

Comment: Still did not run.

Comment: Refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660699/jquery-sortable-only-works-in-document-ready-not-with-a-button

Answer (score 0):

What ended up solving this for me was using the code to create and update the variable but only sending it on button click.  So I put a click event around the get request and that worked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#sortable-stages').sortable({
     update: function(event, ui) {

     var stage = document.getElementsByClassName('stage');
     var stageOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray');

     $('document).on('click','#stagereorderbutton',function() {

       $.get('/stages/reorder', { 'order' :  stageOrder });

     })
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This is a **VERY** bad solution. Each time you drop an item a **new** `click` event is registered for the button. F.ex - when you drop an items 5 times, then your `$.get` request will trigger 5 times for a single button `click`! See demo (reorder items few times and click on a button) - http://jsfiddle.net/2Lqz478m/1/

Comment: I see.  How can I fix that?  I tried the code in your answer below and it would not work.

Comment: I cannot get that to work in my application, it does work in your demo.  Is there a way to clear out the events registered for the button?

Comment: Have you check button `#id` attribute? I see you have different `id` in the question and answer.

Comment: wow, that was it.  I'll select you answer than as it is better,  Thanks for following up, I am relatively new to jquery and probably never would have noticed the multiple sends. Thanks!