# How to use function declaration with jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I have some html/javascript that works in my .cshtml file.
When I try to move it in to jsfiddle to experiment with, it does not work.
Not sure if if it's my lack of javascript experience, jsfiddle experience, probably both....

html:

```
<div>
<button name="startBtn" id="startBtn" onclick="startTimer">Start</button>
</div>
```

(I have also tried "startTimer()" for the onclick attribute; same result.)

javascript:

```
function startTimer() { alert("startTimer"); }
```

When I click the button, I see this in the Console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: startTimer is not defined

What am I overlooking?
(jsfiddle: http://bit.ly/1buQx9t)

Comment: exact duplicate of [Simple example doesn't work on JSFiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/simple-example-doesnt-work-on-jsfiddle) (apart from that you also forgot the parenthesis to invoke `startTimer`)

Answer (score 11):

### [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sQx4H/7/)

**First** you have to set the Framework to `No wrap - in <head>`, instead of `onLoad`.

[image: JSFiddle Option]

**Description**

`onLoad` is the same as `window.onload=function(){[YOU ARE TYPING HERE]}` in JavaScript or `$(function(){[YOU ARE TYPING HERE]});` in jQuery.

`No wrap - in <head>` is the same as `<head><script type="text/javascript">[YOU ARE TYPING HERE]</script</head>`

`No wrap - in <body>` is the same as `<body>[HTML CODE HERE]<script type="text/javascript">[YOU ARE TYPING HERE]</script></head>`

I hope this clears up the settings in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), they can be somewhat confusing.

---

**Second** your `HTML` is slightly wrong:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <input type="button' value='"Start" onclick="startTimer()"/>
</div>
```

**Description**

`onclick="startTimer"` was changed to `onclick="startTimer()"` this will execute the function.

Answer (score 3):

First issue: You have the jsfiddle to set on onload so the function is not in global scope.

[image]

Second issue, you are not calling the function. You are missing ()

```
 onclick="startTimer()"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some weird quotes going on there (in your fiddle) plus you forgot the `()` after the name of the function. Use:

```
<input type="button" value=" Start " onclick="startTimer()" />
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sQx4H/6/)**

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  One difference between yout fiddle and mine -- even after I cleaned up the quote problems -- was under "Frameworks and Extensions".  I had the 2nd option set to "onLoad"; when I changed it to one of the "no wrap ..." options, it worked.  I'll have to investigate those options...

Comment: You don't need to use the onLoad option with your code. Just place it in the head of your document. The onLoad option in jsFiddle wraps your JavaScript like this: `//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
function startTimer() {
    alert("startTimer");
}
}//]]>`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using pure JavaScript in jsfiddle (ie - no jquery, etc), then change the second dropdown to "No wrap - in `<head>`"

Answer (score 0):

You had some extra misplaced quotes and were not calling the function.   Needed to add the () to call it.  Finally you needed to change the "onload" to "no wrap - in "

```
<div>
     <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="startTimer()"/>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are all right; I just wanted to clarify what/where to change with this picture to solve the issue:

Here is the [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mushigh/hkb82nwr/)

```
<button onclick="doThat()">
Click
</button>

function doThat() {
    console.log("click happened");
}
```

[image]