# Simple Button Click not working

Tags: javascript, html

Why is this simple onclick JavaScript function not called in JSFiddle ?

**HTML**:

```
<input type="button" value="Check" id="zeCheck" onclick="check();" />
```

**JS**:

```
function check() {
    alert('ech');
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/franchez/wLVGv/5/)

Comment: the console says: Uncaught ReferenceError: check is not defined

Comment: Change the dropdown that says 'onLoad' to 'No wrap in body'

Comment: same as below. requested to merge:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/simple-example-doesnt-work-on-jsfiddle

hope it helps

Comment: @putvande thanks for this. multiples down votes, sorry was just not aware about fiddle not finding my javascript if dropdown options not changed to 'no wrap' ...

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you are defining this function in wrong place...

Put your script function in .js file or at the end of document in
`<script></script>` tags.

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLVGv/11/)

Answer (score 0):

Take it out from the onload event and it will work. Put it in the body. (left panel)

Comment: this is not an answer please suggest with comment .. thankyou

Comment: @Jatt.net, why do you think this is not an answer?

Comment: @freefaller dear this pretends to like a comment.. if it is all about increasing repo a... you can surely post an answer

Comment: @Jatt.net, ignoring that I'm not a "dear", Bruno has given his answer as to why the jsFiddle is not working. If he gets rep for it, good, because he is correct. Admittedly the answer lacking somewhat in description of exactly why it works, but work it does. I do not believe it deserves rep for this reason, but I do not feel it deserves negative rep

Comment: his reputation is too low to post comment to other questions.

Comment: that s it... answer should be clear as well as descriptive.. so bruno answer behaves like a comment..

Comment: i appreciate you @BojanKovacevic

Answer (score 0):

**onLoad** in JS FIDDLE  is the same as `window.onload=function()` in JavaScript .

**No wrap** - in  is the same as

```
<head><script type="text/javascript"> //your
//code goes here</script</head>
```

So you just have to change it to NO wrap to body.

Answer (score 0):

The function is being defined inside a load handler and thus is in a different scope. You can fix this by explicitly defining it on the window object. Better, yet, change it to apply the handler to the object unobtrusively: http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/

```
$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
   alert("test");   
});
```

Note applying the handler this way, instead of inline, keeps your HTML clean. I'm using jQuery, but you could do it with with or without a framework or using a different framework, if you like.