# why this simple onclick function not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why is this simple code not working? Can someone explain it to me?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zWtZ2/)

I have called the `cc()` function in `onclick` attribute.

HTML

```
<div> hey </div>
<button onclick="cc()"> click me to change color</button>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function cc() {
        $('div').css('color', 'red');
    };
});
```

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/simple-example-doesnt-work-on-jsfiddle

Comment: isn't easier make an simple $('.button').click function ?

Comment: no looking for easier way, looking for the problem origin :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`cc` is not a *global* function.

It is defined with a function declaration, so it is scoped to the function it is defined in.

That function is the anonymous one that you pass to the `ready` method. (And you do that inside a function that you run `onload` due to your jQuery configuration).

---

Globals are (in general) something to be avoided as much as possible, and intrinsic event attributes usually depend on them.

Don't use intrinsic event attributes. Bind your JavaScript event handlers using JavaScript. Since you are using jQuery, use the `on` method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function cc(){
        $('div').css('color','red');
    };

    $('button').on('click', cc);
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zWtZ2/6/)

Answer (score 1):

The code in the `onclick` attribute only has access to global functions/variables.  The function `cc` is local to the function it is defined in.  You'll want to either define it outside of that function (so it is automatically global) or assign it to `window.cc` to explicitly make it global (I suggest the second option).

Answer (score 0):

You should attach the handler inside the `document.ready` something like

**html**

```
<div> hey <div>
    <button  id="mybutton"> click me to change color</button>
```

**javaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //attach the function here
    $("#mybutton").click(
        function (){
           $('div').css('color','red');
        }
    );

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zWtZ2/5/)

Answer (score 0):

CC is a global

I have updated you fiddle with a working example

Html

```
<div> hey <div>
<button> click me to change color</button>
```

Javascript

```
$('button').click(function()
{
    $('div').css('color','red');                       
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zWtZ2/4/

I wouldn't normally do this but I wanted to give you minimal changes to your code.  As you are selecting every single button on div.

Comment: yeah this is much more simple way to do that like he did it before

Answer (score 0):

As said by Quentin, cc isn't a global function.

But also, the function needs to be declared before it is called. So in fiddle, you should wrap the function in `head`.

Updated demo:http://jsfiddle.net/zWtZ2/3/