# Javascript call function dynamically - returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I'm trying to dynamically call a function using this code:

```
function myFn() {
        console.log("called");
}
var callbackName = "myFn";
console.log(window[callbackName]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pr7B2/

However it says that `window[callbackName]` is undefined. Why and how can I call it dynamically? Thanks

Comment: See [Simple example doesn't work on JSFiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431351/218196)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JSFiddle wraps your JavaScript inside a function so `myFn` is in the local scope of another function.

Use:

```
window.myFn = function () {
  console.log("called");
}
var callbackName = "myFn";
console.log(window[callbackName]());
```

This way you explicitly define global function called `myFn`.

Another option (as @Barmar said) is to use the JSFiddle's option "No wrap".

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mgechev/Pr7B2/1/)

Comment: or just change the JSFiddle option to "No wrap".

Comment: ah great. Had the same problem with this code in my external file. This helped. Thanks.