# simple javascript not working in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

I am newbie in `jsfiddle`

I have put a very simple javascript code in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5bMSp/1/

```
<script>
function alertme(){
    alert("HI");
}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="alertme()">click</a>
```

This simple code works awesome in any browser but not in jsfiddle. Am I missing anything in the jsfiddle?

Comment: and [Simple example doesn't work on JSFiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431351/218196)

Comment: Change the drop down on the left side from `onLoad` to `no wrap - in <head>`

Comment: As many of js developer won't expect `javascript` code to be wrapped in `onLoad` by default, the dropdown should be `no wrap` by defualt. Isn't that a `bug` in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, jsFiddle puts all of your code within an `onload` handler, like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    // ...your code here...
};
```

That means your `alertme` function isn't a global, and it has to be for `onclick` attributes to work.

There's a drop-down on the left, near the top, that controls this behavior. Change it from `onLoad` to one of the "no wrap" options to make your function global.

Comment: great... I have been struggling with this for long time. As many of js developer won't expect `javascript` code to be wrapped in `onLoad` by default, the dropdown should be `no wrap` by defualt. Isn't that a `bug` in jsfiddle?

Comment: @veer7: I've been known to call it *"...a **surprising** default..."*  :-) In my view it should default to "No wrap - end of body." But hey, I didn't build it and don't maintain it, so I don't really get a say. :-)