# Javascript onclick event not able to call function

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, scope

Probably a very easy question for anyone comfortable with Javascript to answer. Basically I have a tool bar with buttons in an HTML/Javascript/PHP web app I'm working on:

```
<div class="segmented-control">
  <a class="control-item" onClick='showMapMarkers()'>
    <img src="customIcons/Map.png" width="15" height="20" >
  </a>
</div>
```

... and you'll see the onClick event calls the function showMapMarkers() which right now is not implemented and I'm only using this:

```
function showMapMarkers(){
    alert("show map markers");
}
```

However I get this error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: showMapMarkers

If I write the same alert statement directly into the bar button item then the alert works fine so I guess it's a problem of on-click scope not reaching the `showMapMarkers()` function but I can't understand why.

Any ideas?

Comment: I just tried an example at it worked just fine. Are you correctly importing the function?

Comment: It works fine for me too. The problem isn't with the button.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with importing the function, could you elaborate a little? To be honest I'm really green with Javascript and it could be that I'm missing some key basic knowledge....

Comment: How/where did you test this code?

Comment: Im testing in safari and coding in XCODE. This code still fails to run for me (I'm also testing on android).

Comment: Most likely `showMapMarkers` is not in global scope. Make sure it is, or use a better way to bind event handlers: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
showMapMarkers = function(){
    alert("show map markers");
}
```

Works as expected in my JSFiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/jq5Cf/

Comment: The OP's code also works perfectly fine as well: http://jsfiddle.net/Ab6jd/. Could you explain *why* you suggested this approach?

Comment: I copy and pasted OP's code into a Fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/Xvq8W/) myself, and I also got a ReferenceError.

Comment: That's because you didn't set up the jsFiddle correctly. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5830423/218196.

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed a problem of the scope of the function and the onClick event.

After seeing confirmation that the actual code worked correctly I tried moving the function in to the same div as the button and the function could be called.