# Javascript new random number everytime function is run

Tags: javascript

*I simply set up JSFiddle wrong, I'm new to Javascript and JSFiddle. Please forgive me.*

When I open my app I want a random number appear. And I want a new random number to appear everytime I call the function. But so far I get the same number over and over again.

```
    function number(){
        var number= Math.floor(Math.random() * 230) + 90;
        document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = number;
    }
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e6VFQ/3/

Comment: That code should work. Can you supply a fiddle that shows it not working?

Comment: Sry typo, should be `.innerHTML` that's what I wrote in the actuall code.

Comment: You set up the jsfiddle wrong. Set the second dropdown on the left to "no wrap". http://jsfiddle.net/e6VFQ/4/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple example doesn't work on JSFiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/simple-example-doesnt-work-on-jsfiddle)

Comment: @Juhana You're right. I had no idea the problem was in JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the quick fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hepc4/

No major changes though. Changed the way to show `number`, just to prove that the random numbers are properly getting generated.

**js**

```
function number(){
        var number= Math.floor(Math.random() * 230) + 90;
        document.getElementById("no").value= number;
    }
```

**html**

```
<input type="text" id="no"/>
<input type="button" onclick="number()" value="Generate Rnd No"/>
```

Its working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/KPSF3/1/

You don't get anything in your div because the "content" property applies only to `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements. You should use innerText:

```
document.getElementById("div").innerText = number;
```

Docs for `content`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content