# Why html dom input function does not work?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to create a text field that displays the input right after "go" button is pressed. But when I press the button it clears out all the elements.

**HTML**

```
<div id = "sideMenu">
  <ul>
    <li id="r">
      <span><img class="piece" src="vazirRed.png"></span>
      Red Player<input type="text" id="input" value="name">
      <button onclick="write();">go</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span><img class="piece" src="vazirBlue.png"></span>
      Blue Player<input type="text" value="name">
      <button onclick="write();">go</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function write(){
  var inputRed=document.getElementById("input");
  var redName = inputRed.value;
  var name = document.createElement("div");
  name.appendChild(redName);
  //document.getElementById("#r").innerHTML += redName;
}
```

[The fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ardavanm/2df9Z/)

Comment: Note: The `onLoad` option in JSFiddle affects the scope of the JavaScript you input. [Simple example doesn't work on JSFiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/simple-example-doesnt-work-on-jsfiddle)

Comment: Since IDs are supposed to be unique, you should not be appending an input with the same ID back into the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just using the `write` keyword for your function. Then it's calling `document.write()`, which will replace everything by an empty string.

Replace it by anything else :

```
function writeIt() {
    ...
}
```

**[Update JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2df9Z/8/)**

Side notes :

- Use `document.getElementById("r")` instead of `document.getElementById("#r")`
- Select "No wrap in " in your Fiddle to get inline calling to work

Answer (score 0):

You can't name a function as `write()`.

If you will call `onclick=write()` the function `document.write()` being called. So your DOM is being cleared. And you are not getting anything.

Rename your function.

Put this line in function to add `div` in `body`

```
document.body.appendChild(name);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can't use method write, because The write() method writes HTML expressions or JavaScript code to a document.
doc: 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp

so, please change for your method become like this :

```
<div id = "sideMenu">
  <ul>
    <li id="r">
      <span><img class="piece" src="vazirRed.png"></span>
      Red Player<input type="text" id="input" value="name">
      <button onclick="submitInput();">go</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span><img class="piece" src="vazirBlue.png"></span>
      Blue Player<input type="text" value="name">
      <button onclick="submitInput();">go</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script>
function submitInput(){
  var inputRed =  document.getElementById("input");
  var redName = inputRed.value;
  var name = document.createElement("div");
  //name.appendChild(redName);
  document.getElementById("r").innerHTML += redName;
}
</script>
```