# Minimum value from multiple dropdown select lists like math.min

Tags: javascript, select

I am trying to figure out how to acheive this... I have three dropdown select lists which each have their own values assigned. I'd like to get the minimum/lowest of the three selected values into a hidden/disabled text field (and also a `<span>` so It can be displayed under the lists).

Here's what I'm trying to work with: -

```
<select name="Question1" id="Question1" onchange="code(1)">
<option value="10.00" >This is answer A1</option>
<option value="20.00" >This is answer A2</option>
<option value="30.00" >This is answer A3</option>
</select>

<select name="Question2" id="Question2" onchange="code(2)">
<option value="10.00" >This is answer B1</option>
<option value="20.00" >This is answer B2</option>
<option value="30.00" >This is answer B3</option>
</select>

<select name="Question3" id="Question3" onchange="code(3)">
<option value="10.00" >This is answer C1</option>
<option value="20.00" >This is answer C2</option>
<option value="30.00" >This is answer C3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="LowestValue" name="LowestValue" onfocus="this.blur()" />

<p>The lowest value is <span>//here should be the lowest of three values</span></p>
```

So the user selects 30.00, 30.00 and 10.00 the result should be 10.00 if that makes sense?

```
<script>
    function code() { // forget the parameter
    var Value1 = document.getElementById('Question1');
    var Value2 = document.getElementById('Question2');
    var Value3 = document.getElementById('Question3');
    var LowestValue = document.getElementById('LowestValue');

//I realise this below is wrong but this is essentially what I'm hoping to acheive...
//var total = Math.min(Value1, Value2, Value3);

LowestValue.value = total;
}
</script>
```

The values are decimal(double) because the values are to represent a monetary value (£10.00)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2qae6r52/3/)

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong? It should work.

Comment: It's just not putting the values in to the text input field...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the updated sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/2qae6r52/5/

- [unwrapped the function declaration of `code`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/simple-example-doesnt-work-on-jsfiddle) in the fiddle
- `LowestValueOutput` id added to the `span`
- use `.value` of `select` elements
- use 3 arguments to `Math.min`
- add `disabled` attribute for the last input
- use `.textContent` for the `span` content
- use `.toFixed(2)` for make a string with 2 decimals (checked by `Math.floor`)

Here the HTML code:

```
<select name="Question1" id="Question1" onchange="code(1)">
    <option value="10.00" >This is answer A1</option>
    <option value="20.00" >This is answer A2</option>
    <option value="30.00" >This is answer A3</option>
</select>

<select name="Question2" id="Question2" onchange="code(2)">
    <option value="10.00" >This is answer A1</option>
    <option value="20.00" >This is answer A2</option>
    <option value="30.00" >This is answer A3</option>
</select>

<select name="Question3" id="Question3" onchange="code(3)">
    <option value="10.00" >This is answer A1</option>
    <option value="20.00" >This is answer A2</option>
    <option value="30.00" >This is answer A3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="LowestValue" name="LowestValue" onfocus="this.blur()" />

<p>The lowest value is <span id="LowestValueOutput"><!--here should be the lowest of three values--></span></p>
```

Here the JS code:

```
function code () { // forget the parameter
    var Value1 = document.getElementById('Question1');
    var Value2 = document.getElementById('Question2');
    var Value3 = document.getElementById('Question3');
    var LowestValue = document.getElementById('LowestValue');
    var LowestValueOutput = document.getElementById('LowestValueOutput');

    var total = Math.min(Value1.value, Value2.value, Value3.value);
    if (total != Math.floor(total)) {
         total = total.toFixed(2);
    }

    LowestValue.value = LowestValueOutput.textContent = total;
}
```

Comment: How would I output it so that it uses the double decimal please?

Comment: I added .toFixed(2). Mark the answer valid if it's good for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, choosing this as my accepted answer because you've detailed it quite well.

Comment: Sorry to trouble you again but how could I set it to use 2 decimals only if decimal exists in the value? Sorry to be a pain!

Comment: Added a test with `total != Math.floor(total)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload=function() {
  var sel1 = document.getElementById('Question1'),
      sel2 = document.getElementById('Question2'),
      sel3 = document.getElementById('Question3'),
      lowest =document.getElementById('LowestValue');
  sel1.onchange=
  sel2.onchange=
  sel3.onchange=function() {
    lowest.value=Math.min(
     parseFloat(sel1.value),
     parseFloat(sel2.value),
     parseFloat(sel3.value)).toFixed(2);
  }
}
```