# AngularJS controller function not getting executed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi here is my angular js code. I am a complete novice in angular development.

```
<div ng-app="">
    <input type="text" ng-model="firstname">
    <input type="text" ng-model="lastname">
    <p>Firstname : <span ng-bind="firstname"></span>

    </p>
    <p>Lastname :<span ng-bind="lastname"></span>

    </p>
    <p>Full name :<span>{{firstname +" "+lastname}}</span>

    </p>
</div>
```

You can find the fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/Aneeshmohan/b28jxa4a/1/)**

If I don't add the `ng-controller` directive the whole thing works. But when I adds the directive the whole thing stops working and the controller function is not getting executed.

Actually I am trying something similar to **[this](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_intro_controller)**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple example doesn't work on JSFiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/simple-example-doesnt-work-on-jsfiddle)

Comment: Root cause might be the same. But that might not be the thing which comes first to the mind of someone learning something new. It might  become useful for someone in future. Can't say duplicate

Comment: @Sachu Even if the question is marked duplicate, it doesn't mean it will be deleted. It will be even more useful for someone in the future if they can follow the link to the "root cause".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSFiddle` has a Code Wrap drop-down with a default setting to “`onLoad`”.

The drop down has 4 options:

- `onLoad`: wrap the code so it will run in onLoad window.
- `eventonDomReady`: wrap the code so it will run in onDomReady window event.
- `no wrap - in <head>`:do not wrap the JavaScript code,
  place it in  section.
- `no wrap - in <body>`:do not wrap the
  JavaScript code, place it in  section.

[Here's](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#fiddle-settings-sidebar) the documentation.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/eypr630y/) your working code after I've changed the `onload` to `no wrap - in <body>`

Comment: If it worked, mark the question as answered please. That way people know that it's solved and points can be received.

Comment: Sure.. Was waiting for the minimum time for marking the answer :-) @A.Alger