# jQuery function "prop()" does not work?

Tags: jquery, prop

What am i doing wrong? Please see my simplified Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/a2q815fq/4/

```
function change() {
  $('#mainmenu3').prop('data-badge','444');
}
```

Should change the data-badge to "444", but doesn't?!

I think i'm doing something really stupid, but i can't see it!

EDIT: Thanks for the answers. I think, something in the Fiddle does not work, because an simple "alert('test')" does not work?! Should there be a different call to the function "change()"?

EDIT AGAIN: thx, attr() is working, while prop() does not. BUT, if i choose to remove it, removeAttr() should work for it? But doesn't - see here:
http://jsfiddle.net/a2q815fq/19/

LAST-EDIT: As SultanBaby mentioned, the selector was not correct. Should be: #mainmenu3 a[data-badge]! THANKS guys, you made my day!

Comment: Your function isn't being called in the fiddle because of scope problems. Change the menu from "onLoad" to "No wrap". http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/a2q815fq/6/

Comment: The fiddle you linked to should be set to run in `No Wrap - in <head>` not on `onLoad`.

Comment: Following your EDIT, this is the first comment here done by Barmar: `Your function isn't being called in the fiddle because of scope problems. Change the menu from "onLoad" to "No wrap"`  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/simple-example-doesnt-work-on-jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not see the fiddle before answering, my answer was wrong. Hey, your selector is wrong first of all. The correct selector should be `"#mainmenu3 a[data-badge]"` and you should use `attr` like I correctly mentioned before:

```
$('#mainmenu3 a[data-badge]').attr('data-badge','444');
```

I also mentioned earlier that `data-badge` qualifies as a valid attribute but not a property.

Comment: `.prop()` works. See http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/a2q815fq/6. jQuery automatically converts as necessary.

Comment: @user3395986 Using `.attr()` to update the attribute, not the property because CSS `content: attr(data-badge);` is targeting attribute. EDIT: i see what you meant, because you were wrapping code in `onload` method on jsFiddle, so function wasn't defined on global scope BUT you should read other comments below your own question

Comment: It looks like more relevant selector indeed: `'#mainmenu3 a[data-badge]'` +1

Comment: @user3395986 I changed the menu from "onLoad" to "No wrap".

Answer (score 2):

Use `.data('badge', 444)` or `.attr('data-badge', 444)`

Comment: `.data()` won't work. jQuery implements that internally, not by changing DOM attributes.

Comment: @Barmar is right. `.data()` is for a different purpose than the OP wants to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
function change() {
  $('#mainmenu3 a').attr('data-badge','444');
}
```

Because the attribute is of the anchor, not the list item element. Updated fiddle link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/a2q815fq/9/).

PS: It also seems to work if I leave out the `a` part of the selector, however in this case your markup will be flawed, it just happens to *look correctly*.

Comment: There's nothing in his CSS that says the attribute should be on the anchor. The CSS style is just on `[data-badge]:after`.