# Vertically Center Text

Tags: html, css, position, center

I am having an issue with some CSS within my code. 
Using bootstrap I have created a square which is 400px height, and I would like to have text inside there which is centered vertically. 
I am using JavaScript to change the text when hovered, the issue here is if the text changes to two lines worth, the CSS then no longer works correctly.

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ljprxkrq/3/ For some reason the Hover does not seem to work in fiddle.

```
<div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-4">
    <div class="navigation-links">
      <h2><a href="#" id="text-display" class="network"
        onmouseover="changeText('More network information here')"
        onmouseout="defaultText()">Network</a></h2>
    </div>
  </div>

.navigation-links {
height: 400px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 }

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Even better - make a jsfiddle or similar that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @Adam Fenwick Could i use Javascript/JQuery ? it will solve your issue in a better way.

Comment: @divy3993 You certainly can! I am having a nightmare here

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```css
.navigation-links {
  background: #eee none repeat scroll 0 0;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-4">
  <div class="navigation-links">
    <h2><a href="#" id="text-display" class="network"
        onmouseover="changeText('More network information here')"
        onmouseout="defaultText()">Network</a></h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update:**
 you can add class `vertical-center` with `navigation-links` like `class="navigation-links vertical-center"`

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Ljprxkrq/6/)

Comment: table-cell unfortunately messes with the bootstrap columns, making the square a different size instead of the full column width

Answer (score 1):

Well, ok, let's start with **JSFiddle and Javascript not working.**

> If you do not specify the wrap setting it defaults to "onLoad". This results with all JavaScript being wrapped in a function run after result has been loaded. All variables are local to this function thus unavailable in the global scope.
>
> Change the wrapping setting to "no wrap" and it'll work:

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5830423) - [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0y9qB.jpg)

As for **the problem**:

Seems like you're using flex already. Why not just use it for vertical alignment as well? Append:

```
.navigation-links {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ljprxkrq/4/)

Comment: Never thought of that! Thank you for both parts!