# Unable to make a simple html form and javascript operations work

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with two inputs and a button. When button is clicked, calls a JavaScript function and multiply the two values from inputs. Then show the result in a `<p>` element and is evaluated in a if else conditional to show a letter depending on value.

```js
function showResult() {
  var input1 = document.getElementById('input1');
  var input2 = document.getElementById('input2');
  var z = input1.value * input2.value;

  var y = document.getElementById('result');
  y.innerHTML = y.innerHTML + z;

  var exp = document.getElementById('expression');
  if (z < 100) {
    expression.innerHTML = "A";
  } else if (100 <= z <= 112.99) {
    expression.innerHTML = "B";
  } else if (113 <= z < 300.0) {
    expression.innerHTML = "C";
  } else {
    expression.innerHTML = "D";
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" id="input1">
  <input type="text" id="input2">
  <button type="button" onclick="showResult();">Result</button>
</form>
<div>
  <p id="result">The result is:</p>
  <p id="expression"></p>
</div>
```

Here is the link to fiddle:

[fiddle link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/nbjzh17w/19/)

What is wrong?

Comment: Where does the variable `x` come from? And you're repeatedly appending the result when you do `y.innerHTML = y.innerHTML + z;`

Comment: I think thre is something up with jsfiddle. It works fine in jsbin: https://jsbin.com/pubomaguro/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I have eddited to change x to z and other bad written words. but still not works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple example doesn't work on JSFiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/simple-example-doesnt-work-on-jsfiddle)

Comment: @juhana this answer doesn't resolve my question, or i can understand to resolve it. sorry if duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to

- Load the js in the head
- Directly reference the html element containing the 'result' to change
- Use the variable `expression` throughout, there were several typos
- Use the variable `z` throughout, you used `x` in several places
- Although you can 'chain' comparison operators in some languages (e.g. python), you can't so easily in javascript. You should use `if (100 <= z && z <= 112.99)`

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" id="input1">
    <input type="text" id="input2">
    <button type="button" onclick="showResult();">Result</button>
</form>
<div>
    <p id="result">The result is: <span id="result_number"></span></p>
    <p id="expression"></p>
</div>
```

```js
function showResult() {
    var input1 = document.getElementById('input1');
    var input2 = document.getElementById('input2');
    var z = input1.value * input2.value;

    var y = document.getElementById('result_number');
    y.innerHTML = z;

    var expression = document.getElementById('expression');
    if (z < 100) {
        expression.innerHTML = "A";
    } else if (100 <= z && z <= 112.99) {
        expression.innerHTML = "B";
    } else if (113 <= z && z < 300.0) {
        expression.innerHTML = "C";
    } else {
        expression.innerHTML = "D";
    }
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/nbjzh17w/21/

Comment: Ok, thanks! I have edited my code, but now there's another issue with if else condition. Never show C or D letters. When z is > 113 always show B letter

Comment: @GmloMalo sorry, I forgot you couldn't chain comparative operators in javascript, I've updated the link and edited my answer. If this answers your question please consider accepting this answer :)