# Toggling Hide and show within a modal dialog box with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to show a modal dialog that I created with css on the click of an anchor element, and hide it on click of another element within the dialog box.

I have tried finding reasons for why it doesn't work, but I cannot find it...I'm sure it's a very obvious reason that I should have caught..... I'd appreciate any help or advise.

JavaScript:

```
function show(target) {
    document.getElementById(target).style.visibility = 'block';
}

function hide(target) {
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'none';
}
```

HTML:

```
<a id="as" href="#" onclick="show('modalDialog')">Open Modal Box</a>

<div id="modalDialog">
    <div>   <a href="#" title="Close" class="close" onclick="hide('modalDialog')">X</a>

            <h2>Modalo Box</h2>

        <p>test</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[link to JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/silverstarfy/ex6Lqpov/)

Comment: I've rolled back your change - please don't "fix" problems in your question that will make the answers look wrong or nonsensical.

Comment: If your problem is that nothing happens at all in you jsfiddle demo, then your reason is that you use  inline event handlers (`onclick="show('modalDialog')"`) the default behaviour of jsfiddle is that wraps your code into a function, as of that `function show(target)`  and `function hide(target)` are not in the global scope and are not reachable using  inline event handlers. [Inline event handler not working in JSFiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351), thats one of the reasons why you should not use inline event handlers.

Comment: The question itself is a possible duplicate of [What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone), but the reason In the fiddle might be more [Inline event handler not working in JSFiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/inline-event-handler-not-working-in-jsfiddle)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use,

```
document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById(target).style.visibility = 'block';
```

Since `visibility` does not have a property value called `block`

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/ex6Lqpov/1/)

Comment: Whoops, good catch. It doesn't fix it, but I've updated my code. What fixed it was hanging it from 'onload' within jsfiddle to 'no wrap in head. ' Any idea why that is?

Comment: @Silverstaryu :\ Did you try the demo?

Comment: @Silverstaryu internal scripts needs to be written in head only. If you do not do that, then the event handlers will not be available while rendering the respective element.

Comment: please fix demo link it is showing 404

Answer (score 0):

change the css attribute `visibility` to `display`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11395025)

Comment: My reply is **obviously** an answer to the question. Just because it lacks of a code example to illustrate the usage doesn't mean it is irrelevant.

Comment: It came up in a review, and because it's just one line without any further explanation, or description what it does, it was automatically put in the low quality posts. Technically it's not a valid answer. This should be a comment. The message you've seen above was placed here automatically as a part of a review.

Answer (score 0):

These are the correct CSS properties:

```
- Visibility: hidden or visible
- Display: block or none
```

So your code will look like this:

```
function show(target) {
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';
    //or document.getElementById(target).style.visiblity = 'visible';
}

function hide(target) {
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'none';
    //or document.getElementById(target).style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```