# Why does the compiler says not defined even though its defined?

Tags: html, css

I am running some JavaScript and when I click the button the console says the function its calling is not defined. But I did define it above it. I even logged it to the console and it said its a: *function () {code}*.

Where's the issue?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var userdata = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var pwdata = document.getElementById("passwordfield").value;
  var check = function() {
    alert("hey");
  };
  console.log(check);
}
```

```html
<html>
<h1>Login</h1>
<input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
<input type="password" id="passwordfield" placeholder="Password" name="password">
<button onclick="check()">Log in</button>

</html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inline event handler not working in JSFiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/inline-event-handler-not-working-in-jsfiddle)

Comment: Uh, not 100% sure, but you're closing your html document on line 6.
And the script is defined outside of the html doc

Answer (score 0):

Define function outside of `window.onload` and it will work perfectly:

```js
var check = function() {
  alert("hey");
};

window.onload = function() {
  var userdata = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var pwdata = document.getElementById("passwordfield").value;
  console.log(check);
}
```

```html
<html>
<h1>Login</h1>
<input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
<input type="password" id="passwordfield" placeholder="Password" name="password">
<button onclick="check()">Log in</button>

</html>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```