# Why is defined method not being recognized in jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I have a very simple jsfiddle but it results in an error saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: doSomething1 is not defined` or `Uncaught ReferenceError: doSomething2 is not defined`. 
Both these methods are defined.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fjd4hzcz/3/

**Question**

What is wrong with this jsfiddle that is causing the methods to be not recognized?

My code is very simple as below.

```
<button id="btn1" onclick="doSomething1();return false;">Call doSomething1 method</button>

<button id="btn2" onclick="doSomething2();return false;">Call doSomething2 method</button>
<script>
function doSomething1() {
  alert("hi 1");
}

function doSomething2() {
  alert("hi 2");
}

</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inline event handler not working in JSFiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/inline-event-handler-not-working-in-jsfiddle)

Comment: TL;DR - [change this setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ1ny.png).

Comment: @JamesThorpe, Seems jsfiddle is changed. I cannot find that setting.

Comment: That screenshot was from a moment right before I posted it.

Comment: @JamesThorpe, So what happens if I select OnLoad in JavaScript settings? The methods get defined within the onLoad event, I guess, which makes them inaccessible globally.

Comment: @Suni Refer this screenshot and change the settings on jsfiddle,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5s1O.png

Comment: @JamesThorpe, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the wrap setting in javascript.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that does it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by including the javascript in jsfiddle.
Please select the "No wrap - head" or "No wrap - body" in javascript settings in javascript window.
Hoping it helps you.