# Javascript BMI calculator doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, html

My BMI calculator works in Chrome, Firefox and Opera but not in IE. When I look at the IE Debugger, there are no errors. The problem is that the calculator doesn't show the result. I'm aware that my question is similar to this link 
[Inline event handler not working in JSFiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/inline-event-handler-not-working-in-jsfiddle) however, I can't understand the solution in relation to my problem.

Here is the javascript:

```
const form = document.querySelector('form[name=bmi]');  
const onSubmit = event => {

event.preventDefault();
let healthMessage;

const result = form.querySelector('.result');
const health = form.querySelector('.health');

const weight = parseInt(form.querySelector('input[name=weight]').value, 10);
const height = parseInt(form.querySelector('input[name=height]').value, 10);    
const bmi = (weight / (height /100 * height / 100)).toFixed(1);

if (bmi < 18.5) {
  healthMessage = 'undervægtig';
} else if (bmi > 18.5 && bmi < 25) {
  healthMessage = 'normal vægtig';
} else if (bmi > 25) {
  healthMessage = 'overvægtig';
}
result.innerHTML = bmi;
health.innerHTML = healthMessage;
};  
form.addEventListener('submit', onSubmit, false);
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<form name="bmi">
<h1>Mål dit BMI:</h1>
<label>
<input type="text" name="weight" id="weight" placeholder="Vægt (kg)">
<input type="text" name="height" id="height" placeholder="Højde (cm)">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Udregn BMI">
</label>
<div class="calculation">
<div>
  Dit BMI er: <span class="result"></span>
</div>
<div>
  Dette betyder at du er: <span class="health"></span>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

And here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1nd7oot5/

Comment: developer tools console will show you the errors in your code - internet exploder definitely does not understand arrow function notation - as for let/const ... dunno ... `When I look at the IE Debugger, there are no errors` you're not doing it right then, there are errors aplenty

Comment: Make sure your version of IE supports the "const" and "let" keywords.

Comment: **SCRIPT1002: Syntax error** next line is **_display (46,28)** - which points to `=>` in `const onSubmit = event => {` - opening the developer tools console too late wont show the error, click run in the fiddle

Comment: What version of IE?

Comment: What could I replace the arrow => with?

Comment: I used  version IE11 to test the BMI calculator.

Comment: @Y.K there's a working version for IE11 included in the updated fiddle in my answer. Though you probably don't want to support IE11.

Comment: The arrow has been changed to function(event), however the BMI calculator still doesn't work in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE is too old to handle arrow functions `=>`, from JavaScript's ES2015 edition. You can see this from the IE 'F12 Developer Tools'.

**Consider whether you need to support IE at all.** The code works in Microsoft's current browser, Edge. If you really want to support IE, switch the arrow function out for `function(){}`

PS. You can also swap:

```
parseInt(someString, 10)
```

with

```
Number(someString)
```

To make the code easier to read. You might also wan to add constants for the 18.5 number and the 25 number to indicate what they mean.

[Here's a working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1nd7oot5/4/). However unless you have the extra time or money to support out of date browsers (which, as a learner, you probably don't) I would avoid supporting them and keep your current code.

Comment: that would be a great answer - except IE11 **does** support it - it's the arrow function that breaks IE11 :p

Comment: I would've kept the `let/const` thing in the answer because they too would be a problem with older internet exploder versions

Comment: @JaromandaX yep a lot of things won't work in older browsers. However I'd added advice to dump support for them entirely as the question asker is a beginner and likely nobody is paying them to support out of date browsers.

Comment: Your fiddle solution doesn't work in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Thanks @Y.K. The parseInt() change isn't necessary but it will make your code better. If the answer helped can you upvote it?