# check radiobutton 1, when radiobutton 3 is checked

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

i have html page like this

```
<br>Q1A Making decisions after finding out what others think <br>                 
                        <input name="q1a" id="0" value="0" onclick="MyAlert()" type="radio" required>
                        <input name="q1a" id="1" value="1" onclick="MyAlert()" type="radio" required>
                        <input name="q1a" id="2" value="2" onclick="MyAlert()" type="radio" required>
                        <input name="q1a" id="3" value="3" onclick="MyAlert()" type="radio" required>
                        <input name="q1a" id="4" value="4" onclick="MyAlert()" type="radio" required>
                        <input name="q1a" id="5" value="5" onclick="MyAlert()" type="radio" required>

                        <br>Q1B Making decisions without consulting others <br>
                        <input name="q1b" id="6" value="0" onclick="MyAlert()" type="radio" required>
                        <input name="q1b" id="7" value="1" onclick="MyAlert()" type="radio" required>
                        <input name="q1b" id="8" value="2" onclick="MyAlert()" type="radio" required>
                        <input name="q1b" id="9" value="3" onclick="MyAlert()" type="radio" required>
                        <input name="q1b" id="10" value="4" onclick="MyAlert()" type="radio" required>
                        <input name="q1b" id="11" value="5" onclick="MyAlert()" type="radio" required>
```

if Q1A's value 1 is checked by user, at that moment i want to check Q1B's value 4. analogy is, Q1A's value + Q1B's value = 5.

how can i do this ? 
my rough idea is:

```
<script>
    function MyAlert()  
    {  
      var q1a = document.getElementByName("q1a").value();
      if(q1a == 0){
        $('#5[name="q1b"]').attr('checked', true);
      }
    } 
</script>
```

but this is not working.

```
    <a href="https://jsfiddle.net/zLgmc5be/"> My Code Example </a>
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: You have a syntax error. `document.getElementById("q1b")radio` is not valid syntax.

Comment: can you tell me what would be the proper one?

Comment: IDs have to be unique, you can't have multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: A syntax error in if statement and always remember to have single id. Radio button must have same name but id attribute can be different

Comment: @VinitaWadhwani It's not clear what you're trying to do with that syntax. Radio button elements don't have a `radio` property.

Comment: type is radio @Barmar

Comment: if i change id of each radio button, for each set of Q19, Q20.
i found difficulty in script, thats y tried same id.

Comment: you should have searched on the internet before posting your question here.

Comment: yes i did. @Akshayjain

Comment: @VinitaWadhwani Use IDs like `q19a-0`, `q19a-1`, `q19a-2`, etc.

Comment: first make every Id unique then                                                          if (document.getElementById('r1').checked) {
  rate_value = document.getElementById('r1').value;
}

Comment: Your IDs still aren't unique. You have `id="0"` multiple times.

Comment: first make every Id unique as @Barmar said then                                                                    `if (document.getElementById('1').checked) {
     document.getElementById('10').checked = true;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate IDs, that won't work. `getElementById()` just returns the first element with that ID.

Instead of finding the element by its ID, find it by its value, a `[value=]` selector.

```js
function MyAlert(button) {
  if (button.name == 'q19a') {
    var otherName = 'q19b';
    var otherVal = 5 - button.value;
    $(":radio[name=" + otherName + "][value=" + otherVal + "]").prop("checked", true);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>Q19A Using common sense and conviction to make decisions <br>
<input name="q19a" value="0" onclick="MyAlert(this)" type="radio" required>
<input name="q19a" value="1" onclick="MyAlert(this)" type="radio" required>
<input name="q19a" value="2" onclick="MyAlert(this)" type="radio" required>
<input name="q19a" value="3" onclick="MyAlert(this)" type="radio" required>
<input name="q19a" value="4" onclick="MyAlert(this)" type="radio" required>
<input name="q19a" value="5" onclick="MyAlert(this)" type="radio" required>

<br>Q19B Using data, analysis, and reason to make decisions <br>
<input name="q19b" value="0" onclick="MyAlert(this)" type="radio" required>
<input name="q19b" value="1" onclick="MyAlert(this)" type="radio" required>
<input name="q19b" value="2" onclick="MyAlert(this)" type="radio" required>
<input name="q19b" value="3" onclick="MyAlert(this)" type="radio" required>
<input name="q19b" value="4" onclick="MyAlert(this)" type="radio" required>
<input name="q19b" value="5" onclick="MyAlert(this)" type="radio" required>

<br>Q20A Planning ahead based on projections <br>
<input name="q20a" value="0" onclick="MyAlert(this)" type="radio" required>
<input name="q20a" value="1" onclick="MyAlert(this)" type="radio" required>
<input name="q20a" value="2" onclick="MyAlert(this)" type="radio" required>
<input name="q20a" value="3" onclick="MyAlert(this)" type="radio" required>
<input name="q20a" value="4" onclick="MyAlert(this)" type="radio" required>
<input name="q20a" value="5" onclick="MyAlert(this)" type="radio" required>

<br>Q20B Planning as necessities arise, just before carrying out the plans <br>
<input name="q20b" value="0" onclick="MyAlert(this)" type="radio" required>
<input name="q20b" value="1" onclick="MyAlert(this)" type="radio" required>
<input name="q20b" value="2" onclick="MyAlert(this)" type="radio" required>
<input name="q20b" value="3" onclick="MyAlert(this)" type="radio" required>
<input name="q20b" value="4" onclick="MyAlert(this)" type="radio" required>
<input name="q20b" value="5" onclick="MyAlert(this)" type="radio" required>
```

Comment: myAlert function call is not taking place

Comment: @VinitaWadhwani See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/simple-example-doesnt-work-on-jsfiddle

Comment: its a radio @barmar
nota a button

Comment: It's a radio button.

Comment: @VinitaWadhwani I have `:radio` in the selector, what's the problem?

Comment: i want Q1B's radiobutton automatically checked whenever i choose any Q1A's radiobutton

Comment: That's what my answer does. If you check Q1A button 0, it automatically checks Q1B button 5. If you check Q1A button 1, it checks Q1B button 4. And so on.

Comment: that is not happening on the fiddle but

Comment: Did you change the Javascript option from `On Load` to `No Wrap` in the fiddle, like it says in the question I linked to?