# Code working differently when run in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

This is a piece of code I am running.

```
var passed = 3;

var addTo = function(){


    return ++passed;

}
console.dir(addTo);
```

If I run it from [JS fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/mzLvk57p/) 
I get closure in [[Scopes]], in chrome console:[image]

But If I run entire code in chrome console, I am not getting closure in chrome console.[image]

Comment: That's why the console is used for **debugging**: because it gives a lot of information.

Comment: js fiddle wraps the code in a window.onload callback.

Comment: Right, jsfiddle by default wraps your code in `window.onload` - that's what it's telling you, you can change that in the options - [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mzLvk57p/1/).

Comment: @synthet1c It has nothing to do with jsFiddle.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir um.. yeah it does, js fiddle is decorating the console.log function within the scope of the onload callback.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir It has everything to do with jsfiddle, and its default option.  See my link to an updated fiddle with the option changed.

Comment: @synthet1c Open your console > type the code above > unfold the log > wow! there it is `[[scopes]]`. So where is jsFiddle in all of this?

Comment: you asked for it.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir When you run it in the console, you get `[[Scopes]]` with a single entry.  When you run it in jsfiddle with the default options, you get it with two entries.

Comment: Make sure to UPDATE the fiddle before running it. The closure/window.onload scope disappears

Comment: @JamesThorpe I see now. I thought the question was: why there is a `[[scopes]]` property?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inline event handler not working in JSFiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/inline-event-handler-not-working-in-jsfiddle)

Comment: Is console.dir(addTo); really what you want to do? Don't you want console.dir(addTo());?

Comment: @JamesThorpe I see that its JSfiddle issue. I am following [this](https://youtu.be/71AtaJpJHw0?t=2m51s) tutorial which says above function forms closure. Can someone give a definitive answer if its true or not. Thanks.