# Onclick only every other click

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, settimeout

The problem I have come up to is that the onclick function I have made in JavaScript only can be executed every other click on the button. This happened after adding this code (because I want to hide the class/div after x seconds):

```
popup.classList.toggle("show");
setTimeout(
function() {
popup.classList.toggle("hide");
}, 750);
}
```

So with other words, it works the first time clicking then when the class is shown for x seconds and when I am gonna click it again. Nothing happens, but on the next click it works. And this goes on and on and on. What can the problem?

I tried copying the code but it doesnt seem to work in jsfiddle as it did in the project. If someone could tell me whats the problem in this code and how to make it show the popup every time the button is clicked.

https://jsfiddle.net/xxuvwc1b/

```js
function showpop() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      popup.classList.toggle("hide");
    }, 750);
}
```

```css
.popup {
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: green;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
}

:focus {
  outline: 0 !important;
}

.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}


/* Popup arrow */

.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

.popup .hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="popup" onclick="showpop();"><span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">HERE I AM!</span>SHOW ME A POPUP</button>
```

Comment: That didn't work, when I switched it.

Comment: The fiddle didn't work because of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/simple-example-doesnt-work-on-jsfiddle

Answer (score 3):

You click on it and add the class `show`. Almost a second later, you add the class `hide` (it still has the class `show`).

You click on it again and you **remove** the class `show`. Almost a second later, you **remove** the class `hide`.

The next click adds both. The 4th removes both. And so on.

---

Use a **single** class and toggle that on and off.

Comment: I am new to javascript. May you help me how I would do this single class?

Comment: Replace the word `hide` with `show`, or vice versa. (The rest comes down to your CSS).

Comment: The class start as _hide_ so why would I _hide_ the _class_ again onClick before _show_ and there will be no _hide_ of it. I just want it to be shown at click for **x** seconds.

Comment: You wouldn't hide it again. You are **toggling** it. Since it is there to start it, toggling it remove it (toggling it again almost a second later puts it back)

Comment: _hide_ is visibility: hidden only, _show_ is visibility: visible only in css. Swapping those too as you said only made it reversed. Now the first click dont work, but the second one do and so on.

Comment: @muhammed Don't use two classes. It's visible when it has `show`, and it's hidden when it doesn't have `show`. Then just toggle that class.

Comment: Now I got that part thanks, but this make another problem that the timer will not work properly. It shows until other things is clicked and not on **x** seconds.

Comment: Solved it by toggling show and removing hide in the setTimeout and after that function toggling hide and removing show. Thanks for all help!